# Is there anything special about the init function in JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript

In a lot of code, it's very common to see an `init` function be declared, like so:

```
var someObject = {

    // What is this for?
    init: function () {
        // Call here.
    }
};
```

Are there anything particularly special about the init function that I should know?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For some frameworks perhaps (though `prototype` and `backbone` use `initialize` instead), but there is nothing special about the `init` functions in plain old javascript

Answer (score 6):

**Executive summary:** Like others say - `init` property is not magic in Javascript.

Longer story: Javascript objects are merely key->value storages. If you instantiate an object yourself then it's almost empty - it only inherits some properties from its constructor's prototype. This is a sample dump from Chrome inspector:

```
> obj = {}
Object
+-__proto__: Object
 |-__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() { [native code] }
 |-__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() { [native code] }
 |-__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() { [native code] }
 |-__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() { [native code] }
 |-constructor: function Object() { [native code] }
 |-hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }
 |-isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }
 |-propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() { [native code] }
 |-toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }
 |-toString: function toString() { [native code] }
 |-valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }    > obj = {}
```

-- as you can see, there is no `init` on the list. The closest to `init` would be `constructor` property, which you can read about e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012998/what-it-the-significance-of-the-javascript-constructor-property).