# What is the `constructor` property really used for?

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

In JavaScript, every function's prototype object has a non-enumerable property `constructor` which points to the function ([EcmaScript §13.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2)). It is not used in any native functionality (e.g. `instanceof` checks only the prototype chain), however we [are encouraged to adjust it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4944389/1048572) when overwriting the `prototype` property of a function for inheritance:

```
SubClass.prototype = Object.create(SuperClass.prototype, {
    constructor: {value:SubClass, writable:true, configurable:true}
});
```

But, do we (including me) do that only for clarity and neatness? Are there any real-world use cases that rely on the [`constructor` property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4012998/1048572)?

Comment: Whats my understanding constructor property is used to see whether a particular object is created or constructed by which functional constructor.

Comment: related: [Is there a good use case for the constructor property in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073867/is-there-a-good-use-case-for-the-constructor-property-in-javascript), although the answers are not helpful

Comment: see also: [Why is it necessary to set the prototype constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8453887/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really see why the `constructor` property is what it is in JS. I occasionally find myself using it to get to the prototypes of objects (like the Event object) in IE < 9. However I do think it's there to allow some ppl to mimic classical OO programming constructs:

```
function Foo()
{
    this.name = 'Foo';
}
function Bar()
{
    this.name = 'Bar';
}
function Foobar(){};
Foo.prototype = new Foobar;
Foo.prototype.constructor = Foo;
Bar.prototype = new Foobar;
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar();
//so far the set-up
function pseudoOverload(obj)
{
    if (!(obj instanceof Foobar))
    {
        throw new Error 'I only take subclasses of Foobar';
    }
    if (obj.constructor.name === 'Foo')
    {
        return new obj.constructor;//reference to constructor is quite handy
    }
    //do stuff with Bar instance
}
```

So AFAIK, the *"advantages"* of the constructor property are:

- instantiating new objects from instance easily
- being able to *group* your objects as being subclasses of a certain class, but still being able to check what particular type of subclass you're dealing with.
- As you say: being tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Whats my understanding constructor property is used to see whether a particular object is created or constructed by which functional constructor.

This is a great example for the same:
http://www.klauskomenda.com/code/javascript-inheritance-by-example/

Comment: That article does not use the `constructor` property at all. You might want to read http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html to understand what I'm asking for :-)

Comment: Sorry i mean prototype..my bad :)