# why we use constructor in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the `constructor` property really used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622137/what-is-the-constructor-property-really-used-for)

I would like to understand, exactly why we use constructor in javascript. In which scenario we use constructor.

I know constructor property is a reference to a function that created an object, but need a simple real time example.

thanks in advance