# where does constructor property for prototypes defined with object.create come from?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function myObj(){
    myOtherObj.call(this);
}

myObj.prototype = object.create(myOtherObj.prototype);
```

Does myObj.prototype contain a constructor pointing at myObj function? And if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does myObj.prototype contain a constructor pointing at myObj function? And if so how?

No. [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) will just create an *empty* object inheriting from the given object. In your case it's `myOtherObj.prototype`, and likely that has a "constructor" property that is now inherited (`myObj.prototype.constructor` ===  `myOtherObj.prototype.constructor` === `myOtherObj`).

It's [not necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622137/what-is-the-constructor-property-really-used-for), but if you want to adjust the property so that `(new myObj).constructor` === `myObj.prototype.constructor` === `myObj` you can do that by passing the second argument to `Object.create`:

```
myObj.prototype = Object.create(myOtherObj.prototype, {
    constructor: {value:myObj, writable:true, enumerable:false, configurable:true}
});
```

Comment: from your "not necessary" link, I thought the `instanceof` operator looked through the prototype chain checking against the constructor property, is that not the case? if so thats a bad misconception I've had for quite some time.

Comment: No, [`a instanceof B`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) runs through the prototype chain of `a` until it finds `B.prototype` in it. The `constructor` property of objects in the prototype chain has nothing to do with that.