# Modify the prototype of objects created using Object.create()

Tags: javascript

```
var base = function() { };
base.prototype.doStuff = function() { 
    console.log(1); 
};

var foo = Object.create(new base());
console.log(typeof foo); //object
foo.doStuff(); //1
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xmYQn/

I know there are some similar questions out there, but I couldn't find an answer to this one.

This works, but what if I want `foo` to be of type `function` so that I can add properties to its prototype? In other words, let it inherit the methods from the `base` prototype and merge them with its own prototype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Object.create(new base());
> ```

That creates a new plain object which inherits from a `base` instance (which inherits from `base.prototype` etc). You hardly ever need such a thing.

> I want foo to be of type function

Then define it as a function:

```
function foo() {}
```

> …so that I can add properties to its prototype?

Now you can do that.

> let it inherit the methods from the base prototype and merge them with its own prototype?

There is not much "merging". But you can create a new object which inherits from `base.prototype`, set that to be foo's prototype and then add your properties there:

```
foo.prototype = Object.create(base.prototype); // of course, anything that was
                                               // previously set on foo.prototype
                                               // is now lost
foo.prototype.constructor = foo;
foo.prototype.doOtherStuff = function(){…};
…
```

Then do

```
var fooInstance = new foo;
fooInstance.doStuff(); // 1
fooInstance.doOtherStuff();
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain why this `foo.prototype.constructor = foo;` is necessary?

Comment: @Johan: It's not necessary, [since you hardly need to use the `.constructor` property](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12622137/1048572). If you didn't do it, `fooInstance.constructor` would be `base` (since it inherits it from `base.prototype`). That might be confusing to people, so often it's seen as a good practise to "correct" it. In this answer, it was more to demonstrate the setting of arbitrary properties :-)

Comment: @Bergi if we add `base.prototype.anotherFuncInBase =  function() { console.log('in base'); };` in base . we call it using fooInstance  `fooInstance .anotherFuncInBase()` . How does this happens ? is Object.create points to reference of `base.prototype` ?

Comment: Allright. I suppose it's used to reference the actual constructor function of `foo` (or `base` if you don't change it)?

Comment: Of course it points to a reference, since all objects in JS are only references to their properties. And since `fooInstance` inherits from `base.prototype` via `foo.prototype`, it is able to access the property.

Comment: Might as well ask to be sure :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since I read this very nice series of posts ( http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-objects-deconstruction ), I would go for something like :

```
var Base = { 
    doStuff : function() { 
        console.log(1); 
    }
};

var foo = Object.create(Base);
foo.doStuff = function() { 
      console.log(2); 
    };

var foo2 = Object.create(foo);

console.log(typeof foo); //object
foo.doStuff(); //2
foo2.doStuff(); //2
```

Comment: Since you're using objects you might as well do something like `$.extend(foo, Base);` ?

Comment: But `extend` does clone it at one point in time, while `Object.create` builds a lookup-reference to another object. You can modify `Base`, and all objects inheriting from it (*including already instantiated ones*) will have access to the new/changed properties.

Comment: @Johan here is a difference between the two methods http://jsfiddle.net/xmYQn/1/ ( just as explained by Bergi )