# Confused about Douglas Crockford's object function

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

I know Crockford has a famous object function for inheritance in JavaScript:

```
function object(o) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
}
```

But I am confused, after the line `F.prototype = o`, why he doesn't he reset the `F.prototype`'s constructor, like this:

`F.prototype.constructor = F`

Isn't that common practice?

Comment: You're inheriting, not replicating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't that common practice?

Only when your're creating subclasses (constructor functions with prototypes inheriting from other prototypes).

But that's not the purpose of this code, which basically [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). It takes the part of creating the object which inherits from another object, nothing else. The `F` constructor function is only intermediate and not supposed to be exposed.

> ```
> F.prototype = o;
> ```
>
> why he doesn't he do `F.prototype.constructor = F`?

Because that would change `o` itself. The aim is only to create a new object. Notice that it returns an *instance* of the intermediate constructor, not the constructor itself.

---

Where would the `constructor` be set ([if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622137/what-is-the-constructor-property-really-used-for))? On the *new* object that is instantiated by `object`:

```
 function inherit(chd, par) {
     chd.prototype = object(par.prototype);
     chd.prototype.constructor = chd;
 }

 function Foo() {}
 function Bar() {}
 inherit(Foo, Bar);

 /* Because of overwriting `constructor`: */
 Foo.prototype.constructor === Foo
 (new Foo).constructor === Foo

 /* Because of the prototype chain: */
 new Foo instanceof Bar // true, because
 Foo.prototype instanceof Bar // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an instance of `F` as prototype object itself, there is no benefit in setting the `constructor` property.

For example:

```
function Foo() {}
function Bar() {}

Bar.prototype = object(Foo.prototype);
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;
```

So now `Bar.prototype` is an instance of `F`. We assigned the `constructor` property to that instance which would shadow the `constructor` property assigned to `F.prototype`. So why bother assigning it in the first place?

Generally speaking the `constructor` property has no significance in JavaScript, but it may be useful in your *own* code. I.e. your code might depend on the correct value of `constructor`. But in the `object` function, `F` is just a temporary constructor and `object` just replicates the functionality of [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), which is supported in newer browsers. I cannot think of a use case where you want a reference to `F` in your code.

Comment: Don't pass the `Foo` constructor function to `object`! :-)