# Javascript inheritance constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor

While creating inheritance pattern in JS such as follows -

```
var Fruits = function(){};
var Apples = function(){};
Apples.prototype = new Fruits;
Apples.prototype.constructor = Apples;
```

Why do we change the constructor of the base class?

Comment: If by "base class" you mean `Fruits` - you don't change its constructor.

Comment: My advice: forget about the words "base class".

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fcreate#Classical_inheritance_with_Object.create

Comment: Please see the link above, they change the constructor.

Comment: Consider what would happen if you *didn't* re-set the `constructor` of the new prototype. All instances of `Apple` would have a `constructor` property that pointed to the `Fruit` constructor. We want it to point to `Apple` instead. Instances of `Fruit` should have a `constructor` property of `Fruit` and instances of `Apple` should have a `constructor` property of `Apple`. That's why we change the `constructor` property of `Apple`'s prototype.

Comment: The "*base class*" (as you call it) is *unchanged*. Setting up `Apples` in no way changes `Fruits`. What are you referring to when you say "base class" here?

Comment: @apsillers But even if you dont set the constructor and create a new object, the new object would automatically call Apple().

Comment: Base class - > Fruits

Comment: @apsillers here is a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5nVcT/1/). even if you don't set the constructor, your object will be an instance of Apples as well as of Fruits. It's true that the constructors of the created objects are different but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Or at least I don't see it.

Comment: @basilikum Exactly my point!

Comment: @basilikum Correct, the `constructor` property is *not* a fundamental part of JS prototyping or object instantiation and is *very* rarely used. It's only there if you want to know what constructor is associated with a given instance object. If you decide to use it (or use a library that needs it), though, it's important to have it correctly set. Bergi's proposed duplicate question (and [associated duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8073867/710446)) does a fine job explaining all that.

Comment: @apsillers Ok, I think I can live with that. Those are actually some good reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this example apple inherits fruits constructor. The line `Apples.prototype = new Fruits` means any future `Apple` created will start as a fruit. The next line sets the constructor of `Apple` to fruits constructor. You could do the same thing with out the prototype but then it would only affect the one instance

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the words "base class".

In JavaScript, a function which is used as a constructor (invoked with the `new` keyword) can have a prototype object. The members of the prototype object can be invoked or accessed as though they were members of objects created by that constructor.

Simple example: ( http://jsfiddle.net/G2CUp/ )

```
var djangoFett = { // note that Django here is an object,
                   // not a constructor function and not a "class"
    shootBlaster: function() {
        alert("Blam! Blam!");
    }
};

function CloneTrooper() {
    return this;
};

CloneTrooper.prototype = djangoFett; // note that the prototype
                                     // is an object, not a "class"

var myCloneTrooper = new CloneTrooper();
myCloneTrooper.shootBlaster();
```

In this example we have an object `djangoFett` which is the prototype for objects created using the `CloneTrooper` constructor function. Of note is that `djangoFett` - the prototype for `CloneTrooper` - is an object, not a function or a "class".

Your code snippet is different though - your example has two constructor functions, so let's add another constructor function, to bring my code snippet more in line with yours: ( http://jsfiddle.net/r28QS/ )

```
function Mandalorian() {
    this.shootBlaster = function() {
        alert("Blam! Blam!");
    }
    return this;
};

var djangoFett = new Mandalorian();

function CloneTrooper() {
    return this;
};

CloneTrooper.prototype = djangoFett; // note that the prototype
                                     // is an object, not a "class"

var myCloneTrooper = new CloneTrooper();
myCloneTrooper.shootBlaster();
```

This time `djangoFett` isn't just an object literal - instead it's created by invoking the `Mandalorian` function while using the `new` keyword.

The above code snippet is very similar to the code snippet you provided in your question - I've just added a few more explicit steps along the way. Re-structuring the code to match your  own a little more:

```
Mandalorian = function() {};
CloneTrooper = function() {};
CloneTrooper.prototype = new Mandalorian(); // note that the prototype
                                            // is an object, not a "class"
```

So if I then change the `CloneTooper.prototype.constructor` value...

```
// this is the same as `djangoFett.constructor = CloneTrooper`
// it does not affect the `Mandalorian` constructor function
// in any way whatsoever
CloneTooper.prototype.constructor = CloneTrooper;
```

...it should now be clear that this doesn't affect the the `Mandalorian` constructor function (the "base class") in any way. It affects only one object, which happens to be an instance of `Mandalorian`.

So, why do we change the constructor of the base class? The answer is we don't. We change the constructor of the prototype object. Now, why we do that is another can of worms entirely - and [there are already questions on SO which address it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622137/what-is-the-constructor-property-really-used-for).

Comment: 'Now, why we do that is another can of works entirely' is the main part, The link you gave was not very helpful in understanding why is it recommended in inheritence