# this.constructor.apply vs this.parent.apply

Tags: javascript

Traditionally the object inheritance looks like the following:

```
function Parent() {
   console.log('parent constructor');
}
Parent.prototype.method = function() {
   console.log('parent method');
}


function Child() {
   this.parent.apply(this,arguments);
   console.log('child constructor');
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
Child.prototype.parent = Parent;
```

but this is works too and looks better in my opinion:

```
function Parent() {
   console.log('parent constructor');
}
Parent.prototype.method = function() {
   console.log('parent method');
}


function Child() {
   this.constructor.apply(this,arguments);
   console.log('child constructor');
}

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
// without next lines, constructor will be Parent
// Child.prototype.constructor = Child; 
// Child.prototype.parent = Parent;
```

So,

What is the real reason to use first method ?

What problems I can get if I will use second method ?

Comment: The `constructor` won't be set properly.

Comment: `this.parent.apply` will fail when you create an Object with `Child`

Comment: @Scimonster sorry, edited, the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the real reason to use first method ?

In fact neither of them does properly work. If have another class that inherits from `Child`, `this.parent` and `this.constructor` will not point to the expected function - and you'll either skip a level or get into infinite recursion.

> What problems I can get if I will use second method ?

`(new Child).constructor` would be `Parent`, which is kinda unexpected. See [Is there a good use case for the constructor property in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8073867/1048572). And above problem of course still exists, regardless whether you use `parent` or `constructor` for the property name to refer to your parent class.

For a proper "super" call reference the parent constructor explicitly:

```
function Child() {
   Parent.apply(this,arguments);
   console.log('child constructor');
}
```

Comment: > In fact neither of them does properly work.

http://jsfiddle.net/x9puo0rd/ , http://jsfiddle.net/x9puo0rd/1/

Comment: seems you still not give any practical reason, excluding "unexpected" , for me it is clearly expected, because spec says so.

Comment: @eicto: Please read carefully, I said "*if another class inherits from `Child`*": http://jsfiddle.net/x9puo0rd/2/

Comment: yes, I see the problem , i remember I solved it before, checking how,

Comment: sorry, main question still can be rephrased as "why one can have neccessarity  to write `Child.prototype.constructor = Child` ? I have example  http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/902z097y/ (check end of the `inherit()` function )

Comment: probably yes, btw I just found one case when it may be usefull, if you need to allow your methods to make instance of itself (`var myInstance=new (Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor)()`)

Comment: Yes, `new this.constructor()` is one use case. No `getPrototypeOf` required, though :-)