# prototype object inheritance

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

I'm [Codeyear](http://www.codecademy.com/) fellow and unfortunately prototype object concept is not explained.I google it and found [tutorial](http://helephant.com/2009/01/18/javascript-object-prototype/). After learning,my understanding says that we use prototype object inheritance to save memory and share common properties between objects . **am i right ?** if yes , dont you think the below code is the *bad practice*. Since car constructor has already defined price,speed and & getPrice,why we need to define same thing again,since we are using the concept of inheritance . please  explain . below is the code .

```
function Car( listedPrice ) {
    var price = listedPrice;
    this.speed = 0;

    this.getPrice = function() {
        return price;
    };
}

Car.prototype.accelerate = function() {
    this.speed += 10;
};

function ElectricCar( listedPrice ) {
    var price = listedPrice;
    this.speed = 0;

    this.getPrice = function() {
        return price;
    };
}

ElectricCar.prototype = new Car(); // Please also explain why car constructor 
                                   // is not thowing error since we are not passing
                                   // listedPrice parameter

myElectricCar = new ElectricCar(500);

console.log(myElectricCar instanceof Car);
```

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836064/what-does-anobject-prototype-constructor-do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor and the prototype are two separate concepts. When you apply the prototypal inheritance with `ElectricCar.prototype = new Car();`, it inherits only the methods defined on the object and its prototype, not the constructor itself.

You can actually see the way this works with some quick `console.log()` calls:

```
console.log(ElectricCar);
console.log(ElectricCar.prototype);
console.log(ElectricCar.prototype.__proto__);
```

This returns:

```
[Function: ElectricCar]
{ speed: 0, getPrice: [Function] }
{ accelerate: [Function] }
```

The first line is the constructor.

The second is the actual prototype, as set by `ElectricCar.prototype = new Car();` above. Remember that in the constructor of `Car`, `this.speed` and `this.getPrice` were set, which explains the values of `ElectricCar.prototype.speed` and `ElectricCar.prototype.getPrice`.

What is perhaps least clear is the last line, the `ElectricCar.prototype.__proto__`. This is the prototype of the prototype. `Car` objects have a `prototype` object in which `accelerate` was defined. This prototype is copied over to the prototype of `ElectricCar` in its internal `__proto__` property. This is called [prototype chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Because the constructor is not part of the prototype, and the prototype is all you're inheriting, the constructor for `Car` has been copied and pasted into `ElectricCar`. As you point out, there are definitely cleaner ways to do this. Here's an alternative:

```
function ElectricCar( listedPrice ) {
    Car.apply(this, arguments);
}

ElectricCar.prototype = new Car();
```

See [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for more details.

As for your final question (why doesn't `new Car()` throw an error), as the other answers say, that's kind of how JavaScript works. If you supply fewer arguments to a function than it has parameters, any unset (so to speak) parameters will be set to `undefined`. To demonstrate:

```
function returnMe(a) {
    return a;
}

console.log(returnMe(5));
console.log(returnMe(2+2));
console.log(returnMe());
console.log(returnMe(undefined));
```

This will return:

```
5
4
undefined
undefined
```

As you can see `undefined` is actually a variable that you can pass around (as in `returnMe(undefined)`). For more on this, see [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined).

Answer (score 0):

`getPrice` is such way to create a closure over `price` var in its outer scope, effectively making `price` a private member, *separate* for each different instances, that only this function can ever have access to.

Constructor doesn't throw an error, because supplying arguments to a function in JavaScript is never mandatory. You supply as much as you want and as long as there's named arguments, first from the list you've supplied are assigned to that names.