# Why is 'this' used in javascript while declaring a function to reference an inherited parameter?

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

I am a javascript novice and I don't understand why 'this' is used as a parameter alongside the actual parameter for calling a prototype... In the image provided you can see an example of its use.
So why is it necessary to add 'this' as a parameter? What does it do exactly?

```
'use strict';
function Animal(voice){
this.voice = voice || 'grunt'
}

Animal.prototype.speak = function(){
 display(this.voice)
}

function Cat(name, color){
 Animal.call(this, 'Meow')
 this.name = name
 this.color = color
}

Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)

var Fluffy = new Cat('Fluffy', 'White')

Fluffy.speak()
```

[image]

Comment: Don't show **pictures** of code. Show code. More: meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: If you include a copy of the HTML code where you initiate the function calls it will help to answer your question in the most relatable way to your project :)

Comment: call and apply are a way to pass the reference for which the function is called it sets the calling reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
Animal.call(this, 'Meow');
```

...is used so that within the call to `Animal`, `this` will refer to the same thing it refers to within `Cat`, so that `Animal` sets up its instance properties on that same instance. If you just did `Animal('Meow')`, when `Animal` wrote to `this.voice`, it would either throw an error (in strict mode) or add a global variable called `voice` (in loose mode), neither of which is a desired outcome.

More:

- [`Function.prototype.call` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
- [*How does the "this" keyword work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work?rq=1)
- [*Grasping prototypical Inheritance through pseudoclassical instantiation (JavaScript)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629226/grasping-prototypical-inheritance-through-pseudoclassical-instantiation-javascr) (which talks about this pattern)