# Class vs Function Constructors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Background: C# developer recently diving into javascript

Below are two ways of creating objects in JavaScript. What's the difference between them, which method should I use/prioritize when creating objects and why?

```
class John {
    constructor(name, birth, height) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birth = birth;
        this.height = height;} }

var Person = function(name, birth, height) {
    this.name = name;
    this.birth = birth;
    this.height = height;}
```

Comment: Consideration 1. Do you wish to support Internet Exploder and are afraid of transpilers? Then there is no choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They do largely the same thing. `class` syntax was introduced in ES2015, and does a few things for you:

- It builds in a check that the function was called as part of creating a new object, eliminating a whole class of errors that calling a constructor without `new` allows.
- It enables the use of `super` in constructors and methods.
- It's simpler, particularly if you do subclasses.
- It's **much** simpler if you do subclasses of built-ins like `Error` or `Array` (you can do it without `class`).

But you can do all of that without `class` if you prefer to use the older syntax.

Of course, you can't use the new syntax on outdated browsers like IE without transpiling to the older syntax via tools like [Babel](http://babeljs.io).

(And obligatory note: Using class-like trappings on JavaScript's prototypical inheritance is a style choice, not a requirement. If you prefer, you can just use prototypical inheritance directly.)

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34629365/157247) useful, comparing `class` syntax with doing the same thing with `function` syntax.

Comment: plan is to use webpack and babel

Answer (score 0):

Before es6, constructor functions were how we could implemented class structures and oop.  You still can, but as a c# developer you will be more accustomed to class notation.  As long as the browser supports es6.  They are both functions

Answer (score 0):

The `class` syntax is code from a newer "version" of JavaScript referenced as ES6.

While the `function` declaration was used before and is referenced as "prototypes".

So to answer your question what to prioritize, it really depends on what browsers you want to support. You can check browser support using caniuse: https://caniuse.com/#search=es6%20classes

Coming from C# I think the biggest difference for you will be the browser support thingy. As you don’t know where your code will be run really, you should check caniuse quite often.

As others mentioned there are some compilers that will take that pain away from you as for example [bublé](https://buble.surge.sh/guide/) or [babel](https://babeljs.io/). However, note that they come with their own advantages/disadvantages. Here is the first tutorial I found on the topic: https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-transpilers-what-they-are-why-we-need-them

That being said, welcome to the JavaScript community.