# Stats not defined

Tags: javascript, this, prototype, operator-keyword

Cannot figure out why I am getting the error that stats is not defined when it is...

I have tried naming and renaming and calling the previously named function still getting the error

```
    function GameObject(GO){     
    this.createdAt = GO.createdAt;     
    this.name = GO.name;    
    this.dimensions = GO.dimensions;    
   }

    GameObject.prototype.destroy = function(){    
    return `${this.name} was removed from the game.`;    
   }

    function CharacterStats(stats){    
    GameObject.call(stats);    
    this.healthPoints= stats.healthPoints    
   }

    CharacterStats.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype)

    CharacterStats.prototype = takeDamage = function(){
    return `${this.name} took damage`;
   }
    function Humanoid(PettyHumans){
     this.team = PettyHumans.team;
     this.weapons = PettyHumans.weapons;
     this.language = PettyHumans.language;
     CharacterStats.call(this.PettyHumans)
    }

    Humanoid.prototype.greet = function(){
     return `${this.name} offers a greeting in ${this.language}.`;
    }
```

Comment: **Where** are you getting this error? (What line of the above.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code passes `undefined` to `CharacterStats`:

```
function Humanoid(PettyHumans){
 this.team = PettyHumans.team;
 this.weapons = PettyHumans.weapons;
 this.language = PettyHumans.language;
 CharacterStats.call(this.PettyHumans)
 //                  ^^^^-------------- The problem is here
}
```

Assuming you call `Humanoid` via `new Humanoid`, you haven't set that property anywhere. `PettyHumans` is a parameter, not a property. Either set it as a property, or remove the `this.` from that line.

---

Side note: In a couple of places it looks like you're trying to implement class-like inheritance (for instance, between `CharacterStats` and `GameObject`), but the code doing that isn't *quite* correct. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629226/grasping-prototypical-inheritance-through-pseudoclassical-instantiation-javascr/34629365#34629365) (which I also wrote) for how to correct it, either continuing with ES5 syntax or using ES2015+ `class` syntax. But briefly, the minimal change to make it correct is to add a line:

```
GameObject.call(stats);    
    this.healthPoints = stats.healthPoints    
}

CharacterStats.prototype = Object.create(GameObject.prototype)
CharacterStats.prototype.constructor = CharacterStats  // Add this (and similar when doing other inheritance)
```

Or, again, use `class`. (You can transpile if you need to support ES5-only JavaScript engines.)

Comment: You're the bomb T.J. Going to try that and get back to you.