# anobject.prototype v.s. Object.create(anobject.prototype) assignment

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference the following code as to `prototype` assignments. If so, can I learn?

```
function Person(name, lastname)
{}
Person.prototype.school = `GTU`

function Student(name, lastname) {
    this.name = name
    this.lastname = lastname
}

Student.prototype = Person.prototype                            //   <-----
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype)             //   <-----
Student.prototype = new Person()                                //   <-----
//Student.prototype.constructor = Student

const me = new Student(`a`, `b`)
console.log(me);
```

Comment: **Apace vote down?** with its reason please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are significant differences.

This replaces the `Student.prototype` property's value with the value of `Person.prototype`:

```
Student.prototype = Person.prototype                            //   <-----
```

This replaces the `Student.prototype` property's value with a new object that uses `Person.prototype` as its prototype:

```
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype)             //   <-----
```

(If doing inheritance chains via constructor functions in ES5 and below, that's usually what you want.)

This creates a new object using `Person.prototype` as its prototype, but also calls the `Person` constructor to initialize it:

```
Student.prototype = new Person()                                //   <-----
```

That's not usually want you want, because you're not creating a `Person` instance, you're setting up a chain of constructor functions.

---

As a side note, after you do what you usually want to do:

```
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype)             //   <-----
```

you also want to do this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Student.prototype, "constructor", {
    value: Student,
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

since otherwise, the `constructor` property will be inherited with its standard value (`Person`), which isn't appropriate for the prototype object that will be assigned to `Student` objects. More details about that in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629226/grasping-prototypical-inheritance-through-pseudoclassical-instantiation-javascr/34629365#34629365), but fundamentally, to set up the chain in ES5 you'd do this:

```js
function Person(name, lastname) {
    // Since you're accepting these as parameters, you probably want to store them
    this.name = name;
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
Person.prototype.school = `GTU`;

function Student(name, lastname, studentNumber) {
    // Since `Student` derives from `Person`, let `Person` do its initialization
    Person.call(this, name, lastname);
    // Here we do `Student`-specific initialization
    this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
}

// Set up `Student` as a subclass of `Person`
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Object.defineProperty(Student.prototype, "constructor", {
    value: Student,
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});

// Example of using `Student`:
const me = new Student(`a`, `b`, 1234);
console.log(me);
```

I've added a `Student`-level property (`studentNumber`) to that to emphasize where each set of properties should be initialized.

In ES2015+, if you're going to use constructor functions to set up inheritance chains, there's basically no reason not to use `class` syntax. (But only if you're using constructor functions to set up inheritance chains; JavaScript has other paradigms you can use, you don't have to use constructor functions.) That would look like this:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name, lastname) {
        // Since you're accepting these as parameters, you probably want to store them
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    // Before too long, you'll be able to replace the assignment that's after the
    // `class` with the following:
    // static school = `GTU`;
}
Person.prototype.school = `GTU`;

class Student extends Person {
    constructor(name, lastname, studentNumber) {
        // Let `Person` do its initialization
        super(name, lastname);
        // Here we do `Student`-specific initialization
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }
}

// Example of using `Student`:
const me = new Student(`a`, `b`, 1234);
console.log(me);
```

Comment: @snr - My pleasure! Hope this helped (and that the book does, too!).