# Inheritance in Javascript: hasOwnProperty()

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I was looking into the concepts of inheritance in javascript.
Consider the following snippet:

```
var Person=function(firstname,lastname,gender){
  this.firstname=firstname;
  this.lastname=lastname;
  this.gender=gender;
  this.name=function(){
    return this.firstname +" "+this.lastname;
  }
}

var Employee = function(firstName, lastName, gender, title) {
  Person.call(this, firstName, lastName, gender);
  this.title = title;
};

var e = new Employee('Abc', 'efg', 'Tree', 'CEO');
```

Now, if we check the following:

```
console.log(e.hasOwnProperty('firstName') ) ==> TRUE
```

I want to know is there any way so that we can inherit the values from parents completely?
Such that

```
console.log(e.hasOwnProperty('firstName') ) ==> False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand here that there's just **one** object being created by `new Employee`. That object has a combination of features defined for it by `Person` and by `Employee`, but it's **one** object. All of the `this.x = y;` statements in the constructors create own properties of that object. In fact, that particular example doesn't define anything useful for it to inherit, since nothing is put on the objects that will be in its prototype chain. (The prototype chain is also a bit malformed, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629226/grasping-prototypical-inheritance-through-pseudoclassical-instantiation-javascr/34629365#34629365) for the correct way to hook up `Employee` and `Person` in ES5 and also in ES2015+.)

You can do it differently such that there's an object for the `Person` parts and another object inheriting from it for the `Employee` parts, but if you want to go down that route, you probably want to stop using constructor functions (ones you use `new` with) and use builder functions instead, because the assumptions and standard practices around constructor functions expect a single combined object.

Here's a minimal example of doing it that way:

```js
function createPerson(firstname, lastname, gender) {
    const person = {};
    person.firstname = firstname;
    person.lastname = lastname;
    person.gender = gender;
    person.name = function() {
      return person.firstname + " " + person.lastname;
    };
    return person;
}

function createEmployee(firstName, lastName, gender, title) {
    const person = createPerson(firstName, lastName, gender);
    const employee = Object.create(person); // <=== The key bit
    employee.title = title;
    return employee;
}

const e = createEmployee("Abc", "efg", "Tree", "CEO");

console.log(e.hasOwnProperty("firstname")); // false
console.log(e.hasOwnProperty("title"));     // true

e.firstname = "Joe";
console.log(e.hasOwnProperty("firstname")); // true
```

This key bit:

```
const employee = Object.create(person); // <=== The key bit
```

...creates an object that uses `person` as its prototype. So now the `Person` stuff is on one object and the `Employee` stuff is on another object that inherits from it.

But note that bit at the end&nbsb;— if you do:

```
e.firstname = "Joe";
```

...it will set the property on `e`, not its prototype, so at that point `e` has its own property called `firstname`. You can fix that using accessor properties:

```js
function createPerson(firstname, lastname, gender) {
    const person = {
        get firstname() {
            return firstname;
        },
        set firstname(value) {
            firstname = value;
        },
        get lastname() {
            return lastname;
        },
        set lastname(value) {
            lastname = value;
        },
        get gender() {
            return gender;
        },
        set gender(value) {
            gender = value;
        },
        name() {
            return person.firstname + " " + person.lastname;
        },
    };
    return person;
}

function createEmployee(firstName, lastName, gender, title) {
    const person = createPerson(firstName, lastName, gender);
    const employee = Object.create(person); // <=== The key bit
    Object.defineProperty(employee, "title", {
        get() {
            return title;
        },
        set(value) {
            title = value;
        },
    });
    return employee;
}

const e = createEmployee("Abc", "efg", "Tree", "CEO");

console.log(e.hasOwnProperty("firstname")); // false
console.log(e.hasOwnProperty("title"));     // true

e.firstname = "Joe";
console.log(e.hasOwnProperty("firstname")); // false
```

Both styles of using JavaScript (and several others) are perfectly valid. Using constructor functions is very common (and better supported these days via `class` syntax), but it's not the only way to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely fine, you are inheriting the properties of the `Person` through the call to the parent constructor `Person.call(this, ...)` and you are passing the `this` of the `Employee` instance to the `Person` constructor function.

When you invoke `call` and pass the `this` context of the `Employee` instance, it will actually use the `this` of the `Employee` to do these assignment operations:

```
this.firstname = firstname;
this.lastname = lastname;
this.gender = gender;
this.name = function(){
   return this.firstname +" "+this.lastname;
}
```

Here `this` refers to the new `Employee` instance. Since the above assignment makes these properties appear on the new `Employee` instance as ***own properties*** the `hasOwnProperty` returns `true` when you use any of these properties with the `hasOwnProperty` method.

This is the correct way to do inheritance for *data properties* in JavaScript. In case of *methods* we should put them in the `prototype`.

This is because the data properties should not be shared between the different instances of the `Employee` but the methods can, as they imply behaviour which can be common.

If you do not put the methods in the `prototype` and put them as own properties, it would become an overhead as the same logic would be present but the method would be a different instance for *every* instance of your constructor.

To complete your example, the `hasOwnProperty` is returning `false` for the `name` method as it is on the `prototype`, while other data properties will return `true`:

```js
var Person = function(firstname, lastname, gender) {
  this.firstname = firstname;
  this.lastname = lastname;
  this.gender = gender;
}

Person.prototype.name = function() {
  return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
}

var Employee = function(firstName, lastName, gender, title) {

  Person.call(this, firstName, lastName, gender);

  this.title = title;

};

Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;

var e = new Employee('Abc', 'efg', 'Tree', 'CEO');

//Prints true
console.log(e.hasOwnProperty('firstname'));
//Prints false
console.log(e.hasOwnProperty('name'));
```

The [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) basically uses the supplied `this` context, it has nothing to do with inheritance in general. Basically you are re-using the `Person` constructor function logic and populating the data property values of the `Employee` instance when you do this.