# How to set the prototype of a constructor function?

Tags: javascript

```js
let shape = {
  type: 10,
  getTyp() {
    return "triangle";
  }
};

function Triangle() {}
Object.setPrototypeOf(Triangle, shape);
let t = new Triangle();
console.dir(t.type); //undefined
```

Why doesn't the prototype of Triangle change? `t.type === undefined` but not 10 ;

Comment: why not just `Object.create(shape)` ? There's a warning on very first line on [`setPrototypeOf MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) about this why should avoid this

Comment: By the way, there's nothing in this question that has anything to do with ECMAScript 2019 specification.

Comment: `[[Prototype]]` vs `prototype` is perhaps the most confusing thing in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've confused `Constructor.prototype` with `instance`'s internal `[[Prototype]]`, what `Object.setPrototypeOf()` sets.

You should use the former in this case:

```js
  let shape = {
  type: 10,
  getTyp() {
    return "triangle";
  }
};

function Triangle() {}
Triangle.prototype=shape;
let t = new Triangle();
console.dir(t.type); //10
```

The above works, but, to ensure class `constructor` point to the correct function, don't overwrite the `Constructor.prototype`. Instead, assign properties to it:

```js
  let shape = {
  type: 10,
  getTyp() {
    return "triangle";
  }
};

function Triangle() {}
Object.assign(Triangle.prototype,shape);
let t = new Triangle();
console.dir(t.type); //10
```

Comment: `don't ever overwrite the Constructor.prototype!` ... why?

Comment: @JonasWilms Another urban legend busted about `instanceof`: I've heard that overwriting `Constructor.prototype` will cause `instaceof` malfunction... But, now I found the only problem with it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12260750/8376184

Answer (score 0):

Cause instances of `Triangle` inherit from the `Triangle.prototype`. You want to change that:

```
 Object.setPrototypeOf(Triangle.prototype,/*...*/);
```

If you set the prototype of `Triangle`, you can access the property directly on `Triangle`:

```
  Triangle.shape
```

<sub>Thats basically how static properties get inherited</sub>

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that `Object.setPrototypeOf(Triangle.prototype, shape)` adds an additional level to the prototype chain compared to `Triangle.prototype = shape`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(Triangle, shape)
```

all you need to do is

```
Triangle.prototype = shape
```

[`Object.getPrototypeOf(Triangle)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) refers to `Triangle[[Prototype]]` (or the non-standard [`Triangle.__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property), *not* `Triangle.prototype` as you seem to be anticipating.

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf, the first argument of this function should be an object. You passed it a class.

This isn't what you want, but it's an example of how to properly use that function:

```
let shape = {
  type: 10,
  getTyp() {
    return "triangle";
  }
};

const Triangle = {};
Object.setPrototypeOf(Triangle, shape);
let t = Triangle;
console.dir(t.type);
```

[edit]

Here's another concept:

```
let shape = {
  type: 10,
  getTyp() {
    return "triangle";
  }
};

function Triangle() {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(this, shape);
}
let t = new Triangle();
console.dir(t.type); //undefined
```

Comment: Classes are just functions. Functions are objects.