# how to make custom logging in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

so am doing a cli program and i needed to log the timestamp next to the logged string ,
i used this peace of code :

```
var DEBUG = (function(){
  var timestamp = function(){};
  timestamp.toString = function(){
    return`[${new Date().getFullYear()+"-"+new Date().getMonth()+"-"+new Date().getDay()+" "+new Date().getHours()+":"+new Date().getMinutes()+":"+new Date().getSeconds() +":"+new Date().getMilliseconds()} ]`.red.bold;    
  };
  return {
      log : console.log.bind(console, '%s', timestamp    )
  }
})();

console = DEBUG
```

this worked well  and it would log something like this

> [2021-6-5 17:37:18:13 ] Hello World

what i want is to configure it more and add more argurments  for example if i want to add Task ID  :

```
let TaskID = 1 ; 
console.log(TaskID,"Hello World")
```

and it would log out this

> [2021-6-5 17:37:18:13 ][Task ID : 1] Hello World

and so on , hope you got the point

Comment: Why not use something like log4js?

Comment: so log4js log the timestamp but i dont know if u can add the custome arguments ,i think there is only fatal and error and debug and couple more

Comment: [Overwriting default functions / prototype is a bad idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260375/javascript-overwriting-functions-prototype-bad-practice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do not change the default console behavior.** What you want to do is something like this:

```js
function log(tid, m) {
    console.log(`[${new Date().getFullYear()+"-"+new Date().getMonth()+"-"+new Date().getDay()+" "+new Date().getHours()+":"+new Date().getMinutes()+":"+new Date().getSeconds() +":"+new Date().getMilliseconds()} ]`.red.bold + ' [Task ID: ' + tid + '] ' + m);
}
```

Comment: Thank you , don't know why i didn't though of that