# When is it necessary to set the 'prototype.constructor' property of a class in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What it the significance of the Javascript constructor property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012998/what-it-the-significance-of-the-javascript-constructor-property)

In the Javascript [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) at developer.mozilla.org, on the topic of inheritance there's an example

```
// inherit Person
Student.prototype = new Person();

// correct the constructor pointer because it points to Person
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;
```

I wonder why should I update the prototype's constructor property here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Each** function has a `prototype` property (even if you did not define it), `prototype` object has the only property `constructor` (pointing to a function itself). Hence after you did `Student.prototype = new Person();` `constructor` property of `prototype` is pointing on `Person` function, so you need to reset it.

You should not consider `prototype.constructor` as something magical, it's just a pointer to a function. Even if you skip line `Student.prototype.constructor = Student;` line `new Student();` will work as it should.

`constructor` property is useful e.g. in following situations (when you need to clone object but do not know exactly what function had created it):

```
var st = new Student();
...
var st2 = st.constructor();
```

so it's better to make sure `prototype.constructor()` is correct.

Comment: The `var st2 = st.constructor();` misses the `new` keyword. It should be `var st2 = new st.constructor();`