# What will go wrong if I don't set constructor correctly when subclassing in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning prototype based OOP in javascript recently. After reading lots of websites explaining the prototype mechanism in javascript, I settle down with this approach from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Here are some snippets from Mozilla:

```
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    console.info("Shape moved.");
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();

rect instanceof Rectangle // true.
rect instanceof Shape // true.

rect.move(1, 1); // Outputs, "Shape moved."
```

I understand that `Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);` will set the prototype chain properly so that instance of `Rectangle` will inherit methods from `Shape`.

But the `Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;` line is a little bit confusing.

From [this website](http://zeekat.nl/articles/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html) I know that when we create a new object like `function MyClass(){}`, javascript will set its prototype to an empty object and the `MyClass.prototype.constructor` will point back to `MyClass`. So `Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;` will fix the broken link since `Object.create(Shape.prototype).constructor` still points to `Shape`.

But if I remove this line, I will still get the following code running without a problem. I'm just feeling curious if there's any use case for the constructor attribute? What will go wrong if I just leave it pointing to the super class?

Answer (score 3):

Setting a property this way will make it enumerable(a for in statement would list the constructor property).

```
var rec = new Rectangle();
'constructor' in rec; //true
```

You should be using `Object.defineProperty` or pass in a second argument to Object.create.

```
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype, {constructor: {enumerable: false }});

var rec = new Rectangle();
'constructor' in rec; //
```

Please refer to this thread for more on the constructor property:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4013295

Comment: Thank you for the enumerable part. That's something I never knew. I have tried to run ```rect instanceof Rectangle``` with and without setting the ```constructor```. Both of them return ```true```. Could you point out the difference a little bit more?

Comment: Sorry @adieu, I was wrong about the `instanceof ` operator. The constructor property actually has nothing to do with `instanceof`

Comment: Note that passing a second parameter to Object.create should cause an error in older browsers when you polyfil it correctly. In other words; there is no way to polyfil the second argument to Object.create.

Comment: The link in your answer is very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In your code it doesn't make any difference, as you still create your object using `Rectangle` constructor (explicitly using the name of it: `var rect = new Rectangle();`).

The difference is only in the case, when you've lost reference to object's constructor, or you simply don't know what is it:

```
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
    this.x = 1;
    this.y = 1;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    console.info(this.x + " " + this.y);
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
    Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
//Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

console.info("RECT");
var rect = new Rectangle;
console.info(rect);
console.info(rect instanceof Rectangle);
console.info(rect instanceof Shape);
//console.info(rect instanceof Square); TypeError - Square must be a function, but is still not initialized
rect.move(1, 1);

console.info("RECT2");
var rect2 = new rect.constructor();
console.info(rect2);
console.info(rect2 instanceof Rectangle);
console.info(rect2 instanceof Shape);
// console.info(rect2 instanceof Square); TypeError - Square must be a function, but is still not initialized
rect2.move(1, 1);

console.info("RECT3");
var Square = rect.constructor;
Square.prototype.move = function(x, y) { // just to make it different
    this.x *= x;
    this.y *= y;
    console.info(this.x + " " + this.y);
}

var rect3 = new Square();
console.info(rect3);
console.info(rect3 instanceof Rectangle);
console.info(rect3 instanceof Shape);
console.info(rect3 instanceof Square);
rect3.move(4, 4);
```

I commented out the line with setting the constructor. Uncomment it to see the difference in output. I have also added another way to use the constructor property - another inheritance example (`Square` based on `Shape` but with different `move` method).

So if you don't fix this link, in the case I showed, you will use `Shape` constructor, and creation of objects of the same type will become simply impossible. `rect` was of both types, but `rect2` is not anymore.

So assuming, even if you don't need it, it is a very good practice to fix this link to the correct constructor, as someone working with your code in the future may need it.

**EDIT:**

`constructor` property doesn't affect anything in the `object` itself. It's set once `object` is created to save the `reference` to the `function` which created the `object`. If you will need it in the future than it makes sense to have a correct one. I don't see any other issues.

Comment: Thanks. You have pointed out one possible use case for the constructor property. We could write a function which accept any object as an input and create a new object in the same type. In that case, we'll rely on the constructor property since we don't know which type the input object will be. And fixing the link just make sense. Just wondering if there're more use cases.

Comment: @adieu I have added some comments, and modified a code, providing one more example of practical usage of `constructor` property. Can't think about anything else...

Answer (score -1):

instanceOf will return true if the object is of the specified object type in its inheritance chain.
It has nothing to do with constructor property.

We can use constructor property if we want to initialize property or execute default code at the time of creation of Object.

For example in your example, if we want to create Rectangle always in red color, we can use constructor of Rectangle as follows:

```
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
  this.color = "red";
}
```

Hope this clear your query.