# Unexpected Result in Javascript Instanciation

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm trying to create a grid using javascript prototype inheritance, however there is a problem I could not understand. In some point of the code the "new" keyword seems not work.

It's hard to explain, so the code are below and I put comments in the main points.

```
<head>
    <!-- this is the "parent class" -->
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        // constructor
        function Container(CSSClassName) {
            this.CSSClassName = CSSClassName;
            this.build = ContainerBuild;

            this.components = new Object();

            this.addComponent = ContainerAddComponent;
            this.getComponent = ContainerGetComponent;
        }

        /*
         * methods
         */

        function ContainerAddComponent(id, component) {
            this.components[id] = component;
        }

        function ContainerGetComponent(id) {
            return this.components[id];
        }

        function ContainerBuild() {
            this.element = document.createElement('div');
            this.element.className = this.CSSClassName;

            for (var i in this.components) {
                this.element.appendChild(this.getComponent(i).build());
            }

            return this.element;
        }
    </script>

    <!-- Below I'm using prototype inheritance -->
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        Grid.prototype = new Container('grd');
        function Grid() {
            this.addComponent('body', new GridPart());
            this.addComponent('foot', new GridPart());
        }

        GridPart.prototype = new Container('grd-part');
        function GridPart() {
            this.addComponent('comp', new Container('comp')); // this new keywork seems not to work.

            /* ***** I tried this code, but the result was the same.
            var comp = new Container('comp');
            this.addComponent('comp', Object.create(comp)); // same unexpected result.
            */
        }

        window.onload = function() {
            var grd = new Grid();
            document.getElementById('grd').appendChild(grd.build());

            grd.getComponent('body').element.style.background = 'red'; // ok!
            grd.getComponent('body').getComponent('comp').element.style.background = 'gold'; // unexpected behavior

            // Testing the objects.
            console.log(grd.getComponent('body') === grd.getComponent('foot')); // false, ok!
            console.log(grd.getComponent('body').getComponent('comp') === grd.getComponent('foot').getComponent('comp')); // true?? should be false!
        }
    </script>

    <style type='text/css'>
        .grd { border: 1px solid black }
        .grd-part {
            height: 25px;
            padding: 12px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        }
        .grd-part:last-child { border:none }
        .grd-part .comp {
            background: black;
            height: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='grd'></div>
</body>
```

If you copy and past this code into a html document you will see the problem. The yellow rectangle should be inside of the red rectangle!

Anyone knows what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glancing over your code, I suspect the problem is that every instance of `Grid` and `GridPart` share the same `components` object. You could verify this by having a look at the prototype chain or check the result of  `grd.getComponent('body').components === grd.getComponent('foot').components`.

Don't do something like

```
Grid.prototype = new Container('grd');
```

it adds **instance specific** properties to the prototype, so all instances share the same instance specific properties (like `components`). Instead, use `Object.create` to establish inheritance:

```
Grid.prototype = Object.create(
  Container.prototype, 
  {constructor: {value: Grid, configurable: true, writable: true}}
);
```

and call the parent constructor inside the the child constructor:

```
function Grid() {
  Container.call(this, 'grd');
  this.addComponent('body', new GridPart());
  this.addComponent('foot', new GridPart());
}
```

Properties that are instance specific should be set in the constructor, properties that should be shared are set on the prototype. So in your case you should do `Container.prototype. ContainerAddComponent = ContainerAddComponent;`.

See also [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196)

---

If you are already able to use ES6, use the new `class` syntax:

```
class Grid extends Container {
    constructor() {
      super('grd');
      this.addComponent('body', new GridPart());
      this.addComponent('foot', new GridPart());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I know how to use Object.create for inheritance! I've tried before but without success. Thank you for the answer, it solved my problem. I will see about ES6 too. I didn't know that It was available already! Thank you :)

Comment: I don't think the class syntax is supported by any browser yet, but there are transformation tools that convert this to valid ES5 code. For example http://www.phpied.com/writing-es6-today-with-jstransform/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that the `new` keyword is not working anymore but rather it lies in the following line:
`GridPart.prototype = new Container('grd-part');`

What it does is cause all `GridPart` objects to have the same `this.components` object.

So when you call `this.addComponent` inside the `GridPart` constructor function you override the same `this.components` object at index `'comp'` with a new `Container` object

I've found a way to achieve the inheritance you are looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9882720/1569638)
and integrated this solution into your code.

here is a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hqneu)