# Calling a Prototype's Function

Tags: javascript

When I run the following script, I get the error that `sub.hello` is not a function. Why not? `Sub`'s prototype is `Base` and `Base` has the function `hello`. Since `Sub` does not have the function `hello`, shouldn't its prototype then be checked for the function?

```
function Base() {

}
Base.prototype.hello = function() {
    alert("hello");
}

Sub.prototype = Base;
function Sub() {
    Base.call(this);
}

var sub = new Sub();
sub.hello();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to do inheritance in JavaScript is to use the `Object.create` function:

```
function Base() {

}
Base.prototype.hello = function() {
    alert("hello");
}

function Sub() {
    Base.call(this);
}
Sub.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);

// Restore constructor property
Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;

var sub = new Sub();
sub.hello();
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5stg6hzy/)

For further reading, check the [Mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: Don't forget to set `Sub.prototype.constructor = Sub;` since you've overridden Sub's constructor with Base's constructor.

Comment: Yep it still runs, my concern targets cases wherein the constructor property provides useful, cases such as **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012998/what-it-the-significance-of-the-javascript-constructor-property#answer-9882720)**.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit, @ryeballar: Setting `Sub.prototype` to `Object.create(Base.prototype)` override's `Sub`'s constructor with  `Base`'s? Also, why do we pass `Base.prototype` in `Object.create()` instead of `Base`?

Comment: @hendryau no it doesn't, see http://jsfiddle.net/5stg6hzy/1/, but there is a corner case where code could rely on `prototype.constructor` for whatever reason, see link of ryeballer

Comment: @hendryau answer to your second question: because you only want to clone the `Base`'s prototype. As calling the `Base`'s constructor is handled in `Sub`'s constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The function must exist on the prototype, not on the prototype's prototype.

You've effectively done this:

```
Sub.prototype.prototype.hello = function () { }
```

So, instead of `Base.prototype.hello`, either use `Base.hello`:

```js
function Base() { }

Base.hello = function() { alert("hello"); }

Sub.prototype = Base;

function Sub() {
    Base.call(this);
}

var sub = new Sub();
sub.hello();
```

Or make `Sub.prototype` and *instance* of `Base`:

```js
function Base() { }

Base.prototype.hello = function() { alert("hello"); }

Sub.prototype = new Base;

function Sub() {
    Base.call(this);
}

var sub = new Sub();
sub.hello();
```

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Downvote posts, not people. Don't be a jerk just because you are wrong and I pointed it out. This is in the rules of this site. I watched your reputation decrease by 1 in the exact instant that you deleted your answer and my received a downvote.

Comment: I downvote because you removed hello from Base's prototype. Don't be a smartass and show him the real way of inheriting in js

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit My post *does* show the "real" way of inheriting in JS.

Comment: What will you do if you need to inherit from `Sub`?

Comment: And now you're executing the Base constructor in `Sub.prototype = new Base;`, you've got it wrong twice now :)

Comment: @meagar using your first snippet, if I run `var base = new Base(); base.hello();`, `hello` is not defined for `base`, why is that?

Comment: @hendryau That's not the case, if you've used the code I've posted: `function Base() { };

Base.prototype.hello = function() { alert("hello"); };

x = new Base;
x.hello; // => 
function () { alert("hello"); }`

Comment: @meagar I used the first snippet, not the second.

Comment: @meagar You're first snippet is confusing, if you're trying to create an abstract class that cannot be instantiated then I think its better to create an Object with static methods that will be assigned to Sub's prototype.

Comment: Furthermore, the second snippet actually invokes the Base constructor as opposed to @WouterHuysentruit answer wherein using `Object.create(Base.prototype)` does not. There's nothing wrong with it, it just invokes the constructor unnecessarily.