# Javascript OOP - Skipping setting the child constructor

Tags: javascript

Okay, so I'm trying to get my head around Javascript OOP and it's lovely mix of prototypes, prototype pointers, and constructors.  I was reading the MDN introduction (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) and it had the following example:

```
// Define the Person constructor
var Person = function(firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
};

// Add a couple of methods to Person.prototype
Person.prototype.walk = function(){
  console.log("I am walking!");
};

Person.prototype.sayHello = function(){
  console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName);
};

// Define the Student constructor
function Student(firstName, subject) {
  // Call the parent constructor, making sure (using Function#call)
  // that "this" is set correctly during the call
  Person.call(this, firstName);

  // Initialize our Student-specific properties
  this.subject = subject;
};

// Create a Student.prototype object that inherits from Person.prototype.
// Note: A common error here is to use "new Person()" to create the
// Student.prototype. That's incorrect for several reasons, not least 
// that we don't have anything to give Person for the "firstName" 
// argument. The correct place to call Person is above, where we call 
// it from Student.
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype); // See note below

// Set the "constructor" property to refer to Student
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;

// Replace the "sayHello" method
Student.prototype.sayHello = function(){
  console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName + ". I'm studying "
              + this.subject + ".");
};

// Add a "sayGoodBye" method
Student.prototype.sayGoodBye = function(){
  console.log("Goodbye!");
};

// Example usage:
var student1 = new Student("Janet", "Applied Physics");
student1.sayHello();   // "Hello, I'm Janet. I'm studying Applied Physics."
student1.walk();       // "I am walking!"
student1.sayGoodBye(); // "Goodbye!"

// Check that instanceof works correctly
console.log(student1 instanceof Person);  // true 
console.log(student1 instanceof Student); // true
```

But if I test it out, and comment out the line:

```
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;
```

Everything works exactly the same.  What's going on?  Is there something important not being set that will bite my ass later?

Comment: if you log a student instance in chrome Dev tools it'll say its a Person when you don't repair the constructor property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create `Student`...

```js
function Student() {
    /* ... */
}
```

... it automatically has a `prototype` object with a own `constructor` property:

```js
Student.prototype.hasOwnProperty('constructor'); // true
Student.prototype.constructor;                   // Student
```

However, the code overwrites that `prototype` with another object:

```js
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
```

Therefore, now `Student.prototype` does no longer have an own `constructor` property. Instead, it inherits a `constructor` property from `Person.prototype`:

```js
Student.prototype.hasOwnProperty('constructor'); // false
Student.prototype.constructor;                   // Person
```

Therefore, the code creates the `constructor` property to the new `prototype`:

```js
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;
Student.prototype.hasOwnProperty('constructor'); // true
Student.prototype.constructor;                   // Student
```

Comment: But how come it works exactly the same when I comment out the `Student.prototype.constructor = Student;` line?

Comment: @Russbear No, it isn't the same. Try `new Student().constructor`. If you remove that line, it returns `Person` instead of `Student`.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it.  The duplicate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012998/what-it-the-significance-of-the-javascript-constructor-property says  "The constructor property makes absolutely no practical difference to anything internally. It's only any use if your code explicitly uses it. "