# Call static methods from regular ES6 class methods

Tags: javascript, class, static, ecmascript-6, es6-class

What's the standard way to call static methods? I can think of using `constructor` or using the name of the class itself, I don't like the latter since it doesn't feel necessary. Is the former the recommended way, or is there something else?

Here's a (contrived) example:

```
class SomeObject {
  constructor(n){
    this.n = n;
  }

  static print(n){
    console.log(n);
  }

  printN(){
    this.constructor.print(this.n);
  }
}
```

Comment: `SomeObject.print` feels natural. But `this.n` inside makes no sense since there is no instance, if we are talking about static methods.

Comment: @dfsq `printN` is not static though.

Comment: You are right, confused names.

Comment: I am curious why this question does not have so many upvotes! Isn't this a common practice for creating utility functions?

Comment: @Thoran no, not really common practice. An anti-pattern, more like. Typically static and non-static methods are *radically* different. Unifying them can be done (as demonstrated) but actually serves no useful OOP purpose. Instance methods work on an instance using the data *from* that instance. Just forwarding the call to a static method does none of that. Moreover, static methods are often a signal of where OOP itself breaks down as it's the only way to model non-instance blocks of functionality. For which JS already has functions anyway.

Comment: @VLAZ: For those of us steeped in Smalltalk (the benchmark of expected and proper OO behavior), "static" is the ES6 way of spelling "class". In normal OO practice, a static method is a method on the CLASS of an object, rather than an instance. There are all sorts of useful OOP purposes for that. One example is managing registries that associate an identifier with an instance and insure that just one instance exists for each identifier. Another useful purpose is to provide certain universal methods that are guaranteed to be defined on every object. An example is exception throwing behavior.

Comment: @TomStambaugh that's just workarounds for not having "free methods" (or functions). The usefulness you describe is just bundling these non-existent top-level constructs in a common module/namespace/organisation. "Pure" OO just doesn't have that top level concept and burdens classes with the organisational part of things.

Comment: @VLAZ: Perhaps because I began programming in Smalltalk (in 1982), I've always found that free methods serve no useful OOP purpose :). I guess it's a matter of perspective. In any case, happy 2024!

Answer (score 256):

Both ways are viable, but they do different things when it comes to inheritance with an overridden static method. Choose the one whose behavior you expect:

```
class Super {
  static whoami() {
    return "Super";
  }
  lognameA() {
    console.log(Super.whoami());
  }
  lognameB() {
    console.log(this.constructor.whoami());
  }
}
class Sub extends Super {
  static whoami() {
    return "Sub";
  }
}
new Sub().lognameA(); // Super
new Sub().lognameB(); // Sub
```

Referring to the static property via the class will be actually static and constantly give the same value. Using `this.constructor` instead will use dynamic dispatch and refer to the class of the current instance, where the static property *might* have the inherited value but could also be overridden.

This matches the behavior of Python, where you can choose to refer to static properties either via the class name or the instance `self`.

If you expect static properties not to be overridden (and always refer to the one of the current class), [like in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2223386/1048572), use the explicit reference.

Comment: can you explain the constructor property vs class method definition?

Comment: @Chris: Every class *is* a constructor function (just like you know it from ES5 without `class` syntax), there is no difference in the definition of the method. It's just a matter of how you look it up, via [the inherited `constructor` property](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4012998/1048572) or directly by its name.

Comment: Another example is [PHP's Late Static Bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). Not only does this.constructor respect inheritance, but also helps you avoid having to update code if you change the class name.

Comment: @ricanontherun Having to update the code when you change variable names is not an argument against using names. Also refactoring tools can do it automatically anyway.

Comment: How to implement this in typescript ? It gives the error `Property 'staticProperty' does not exist on type 'Function'`

Comment: @ayZagen I dunno, I guess you should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about how to do the TypeScript typing for this, and post the non-working code there.

Answer (score 86):

I stumbled over this thread searching for answer to similar case. Basically all answers are found, but it's still hard to extract the essentials from them.

### Kinds of Access

Assume a class `Foo` probably derived from some other `class(es)` with probably more classes derived from it.

Then accessing:

- **from `static`** method/getter of `Foo` class:

  - some probably **overridden `static`** method/getter:

    - `this.method()`
    - `this.property`
  - some probably **overridden instance** method/getter:

    - *impossible by design*
  - own **non-overridden static** method/getter:

    - `Foo.method()`
    - `Foo.property`
  - own **non-overridden instance** method/getter:

    - *impossible by design*
- **from instance** method/getter of `Foo` class:

  - some probably **overridden `static`** method/getter:

    - `this.constructor.method()`
    - `this.constructor.property`
  - some probably **overridden instance** method/getter:

    - `this.method()`
    - `this.property`
  - own **non-overridden `static`** method/getter:

    - `Foo.method()`
    - `Foo.property`
  - own **non-overridden instance** method/getter:

    - *not possible by intention unless using some workaround*:

      - `Foo.prototype.method.call( this )`
      - `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Foo.prototype,'<property>' ).get.call(this)`

> Keep in mind that using `this` isn't working this way when using arrow `functions` or invoking methods/getters explicitly bound to custom value.

### Background

- When in context of an instance's method/getter

  - `this` is referring to current instance.
  - `super` is basically referring to same instance, but somewhat addressing methods/getters written in context of some `class` current one is extending (by using the prototype of `Foo`'s prototype).
  - definition of instance's `class` used on creating it is available per `this.constructor`.
- When in context of a `static` method/getter there is no "current instance" by intention and so:

  - `this` is available to refer to the definition of current `class` directly.
  - `super` is not referring to some instance either, but to `static` methods/getters written in context of some `class` current one is extending.

## Conclusion

Try this code:

```js
class A {
  constructor( input ) {
    this.loose = this.constructor.getResult( input );
    this.tight = A.getResult( input );
    console.log( this.scaledProperty, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( A.prototype, "scaledProperty" ).get.call( this ) );
  }

  get scaledProperty() {
    return parseInt( this.loose ) * 100;
  }
  
  static getResult( input ) {
    return input * this.scale;
  }
  
  static get scale() {
    return 2;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor( input ) {
    super( input );
    this.tight = B.getResult( input ) + " (of B)";
  }
  
  get scaledProperty() {
    return parseInt( this.loose ) * 10000;
  }

  static get scale() {
    return 4;
  }
}

class C extends B {
  constructor( input ) {
    super( input );
  }
  
  static get scale() {
    return 5;
  }
}

class D extends C {
  constructor( input ) {
    super( input );
  }
  
  static getResult( input ) {
    return super.getResult( input ) + " (overridden)";
  }
  
  static get scale() {
    return 10;
  }
}


let instanceA = new A( 4 );
console.log( "A.loose", instanceA.loose );
console.log( "A.tight", instanceA.tight );

let instanceB = new B( 4 );
console.log( "B.loose", instanceB.loose );
console.log( "B.tight", instanceB.tight );

let instanceC = new C( 4 );
console.log( "C.loose", instanceC.loose );
console.log( "C.tight", instanceC.tight );

let instanceD = new D( 4 );
console.log( "D.loose", instanceD.loose );
console.log( "D.tight", instanceD.tight );
```

Comment: `Own non-overridden instance method/getter / not possible by intention unless using some workaround` --- That's a real pity. In my opinion, this is a shortcoming of ES6+. Maybe it should be updated to allow simply referring to `method` -- i.e. `method.call(this)`. Better than `Foo.prototype.method`. Babel/etc. could implement using an NFE (named function expression).

Comment: `method.call( this )` is a probable solution except for the `method` isn't bound to the desired base "class" then and thus fails to be a _non-overriden instance method/getter_. It's always possible to work with class-independent methods that way. Nonetheless I don't think current design is that bad. In context of objects of class derived from your base class Foo there may be good reasons to override an instance method. That overriden method may have good reasons to invoke its `super` implementation or not. Either case is eligible and should be obeyed. Otherwise it would end in bad OOP design.

Comment: Despite the OOP sugar, ES methods are still _functions_, and people will want to use and reference them as such. My problem with ES class syntax is that it provides no direct reference to the currently executing method -- something that used to be easy via `arguments.callee` or an NFE.

Comment: Sounds like bad practice or at least bad software design anyway. I'd consider both points of view contrary to each other, as I don't see eligible reason in context of OOP paradigm that involves accessing currently invoked method by reference (which is not just its context as is available via `this`). It sound like trying to mix benefits of pointer arithmetics of bare C with higher-level C#. Just out of curiosity: what would you use `arguments.callee` for in cleanly designed OOP code?

Comment: I'm working in a large project built with Dojo's class system, which allows calling the superclass(es) implementation(s) of the current method via `this.inherited(currentFn, arguments);` -- where `currentFn` is a reference to the currently executing function. Not being able to reference the currently executing function directly is making it a little hairy in TypeScript, which takes its class syntax from ES6.

Comment: I see! This is mostly due to heterogenic setups demanding to mix the old world with the new one. I was using similar approach in a project myself and the reference on current method is required indeed for traversing the prototype chain to prevent infinite regressions when looking for next overloaded version. However this is past in a purely ES6 project. So, for now I stick with old code in old projects or try deriving from old-style classes and start using ES6 inheritance handling in such derived classes, only, though I don't know the specifics of Dojo classes, thus can't tell about your case.

Answer (score 22):

If you are planning on doing any kind of inheritance, then I would recommend `this.constructor`. This simple example should illustrate why:

```js
class ConstructorSuper {
  constructor(n){
    this.n = n;
  }

  static print(n){
    console.log(this.name, n);
  }

  callPrint(){
    this.constructor.print(this.n);
  }
}

class ConstructorSub extends ConstructorSuper {
  constructor(n){
    this.n = n;
  }
}

let test1 = new ConstructorSuper("Hello ConstructorSuper!");
console.log(test1.callPrint());

let test2 = new ConstructorSub("Hello ConstructorSub!");
console.log(test2.callPrint());
```

- `test1.callPrint()` will log `ConstructorSuper Hello ConstructorSuper!` to the 
  console
- `test2.callPrint()` will log `ConstructorSub Hello ConstructorSub!` to the console

The named class will not deal with inheritance nicely unless you explicitly redefine every function that makes a reference to the named Class. Here is an example:

```js
class NamedSuper {
  constructor(n){
    this.n = n;
  }

  static print(n){
    console.log(NamedSuper.name, n);
  }

  callPrint(){
    NamedSuper.print(this.n);
  }
}

class NamedSub extends NamedSuper {
  constructor(n){
    this.n = n;
  }
}

let test3 = new NamedSuper("Hello NamedSuper!");
console.log(test3.callPrint());

let test4 = new NamedSub("Hello NamedSub!");
console.log(test4.callPrint());
```

- `test3.callPrint()` will log `NamedSuper Hello NamedSuper!` to the 
  console
- `test4.callPrint()` will log `NamedSuper Hello NamedSub!` to the console

[See all the above running in Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&playground=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20ConstructorSuper%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(n)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.n%20%3D%20n%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20static%20print(n)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this.name%2C%20n)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20callPrint()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.constructor.print(this.n)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ConstructorSub%20extends%20ConstructorSuper%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(n)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.n%20%3D%20n%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test1%20%3D%20new%20ConstructorSuper(%22Hello%20ConstructorSuper!%22)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(test1.callPrint())%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test2%20%3D%20new%20ConstructorSub(%22Hello%20ConstructorSub!%22)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(test2.callPrint())%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20NamedSuper%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(n)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.n%20%3D%20n%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20static%20print(n)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(NamedSuper.name%2C%20n)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20callPrint()%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20NamedSuper.print(this.n)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20NamedSub%20extends%20NamedSuper%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(n)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.n%20%3D%20n%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test3%20%3D%20new%20NamedSuper(%22Hello%20NamedSuper!%22)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(test3.callPrint())%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20test4%20%3D%20new%20NamedSub(%22Hello%20NamedSub!%22)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(test4.callPrint())%3B).

You can see from this that `test4` still thinks it's in the super class; in this example it might not seem like a huge deal, but if you are trying to reference member functions that have been overridden or new member variables, you'll find yourself in trouble.

Comment: But static function are no overridden member methods? Usually you are trying *not* to reference any overridden stuff statically.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure I understand what you are pointing out, but one specific case I have come across would is with MVC model hydration patterns. Sub classes extending a model may want to implement a static hydrate function. However, when these are hard-coded in, base model instances are only ever returned. This is a pretty specific example, but many patterns that rely on having a static collection of registered instances would be effected by this. One big disclaimer is that we are trying to simulate classical inheritance here, rather than prototypal inheritance... And that is not popular :P

Comment: Yeah, as I concluded now in my own answer this is not even solved consistently in "classical" inheritance - sometimes you might want overrides, sometimes not. The first part of my comment pointed at static class functions, which I did not consider to be "members". Better ignore it :-)