# ES6 class member to be a class itself

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

in es6 a class can have methods and static methods as its members. can it also have classes as members? (because Class is actually kind of function itself?)
i would like it to build nested classes.

```
class foo {
  barMethod {
    // do something for the instance
  }
  static bamMethod {
    // do something
  }

  // e.g.
  class batClass {
    // the constructor and other stuff for batClass 
  }

}

new foo.batClass();
```

Comment: You could do `foo.batClass = class { ... }`

Comment: What, why there are so many downwotes, it's an interesting question actually.

Answer (score 0):

[No.] ([Nested ES6 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784375/nested-es6-classes)). Read this post. You can only do as @floribon mentioned in comment.