# Trying to call a static method from an imported ES6 module

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I'm using Firefox 56 with `dom.moduleScripts.enabled` set to true. This allows me to work with native ES6 modules.

I have a vue2 component which has a method defined:

```
import StorageZonesAjaxMethods from '../../ajax/storage-zones.js';
....
methods: {
        updateList() 
        {
            //console.log(StorageZonesAjaxMethods);
            StorageZonesAjaxMethods.getList();//function(response) { this.list = response.data.payload;});

        },
    },
```

where the class with the methods is:

```
export default new class StorageZonesAjaxMethods {

    static getItem(id, then)
    {
        axios.get(`${Config.apiBaseUrl}/storage-zones/${id}`)
            .then(response => then);
    }

    static getList(then)
    {
        alert('in get list');
        axios.get(`${Config.apiBaseUrl}/storage-zones`)
            .then(response => then);
    }
```

I get the error `"TypeError: (intermediate value).getList is not a function"` in firefx, but the console.log shows it is, but it's inside a constructor for some reason. What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

[Never use `new class { … }`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38739499/1048572)!

And [don't default-export a `class` with only `static` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29895235/1048572) either. Simplify to

```
export default {
    getItem(id) {
        return axios.get(`${Config.apiBaseUrl}/storage-zones/${id}`);
    }
    getList() {
        alert('in get list');
        return axios.get(`${Config.apiBaseUrl}/storage-zones`);
    }
};
```

Or even better change both files and use

```
export function getItem(id) {
    return axios.get(`${Config.apiBaseUrl}/storage-zones/${id}`);
}
export function getList() {
    alert('in get list');
    return axios.get(`${Config.apiBaseUrl}/storage-zones`);
}
```

```
import * as StorageZonesAjaxMethods from '../../ajax/storage-zones.js';
```

Comment: I come from the world of real coding. A class of static methods is no code smell! I considered just exporting the object, but I'd rather group sementically, cause, you know, that's what a class is for.

Comment: @user3791372 I don't know what you mean by "world of real coding", but in JS it definitely is a code smell. Using classes for organising code is a Java technique. JS has modules and objects for this as first-class citizens.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson learnt - don't code with tired eyes. `export default new class StorageZonesAjaxMethods` in the class shouldn't have a `new` there