# Can I use classes inside the Javascript module pattern?

Tags: javascript, class, module, module-pattern

I'm currently working on an app which uses the javascript module pattern (http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html). Can javascript classes be used in combination with this pattern to create a structure like in C#, where classes are nested inside namespaces?

I've currently got this:

```
app.modules.foo = class {
    constructor() {
        // Module variables
    }

    // Module functions

    get init() {
        // Module initialization function
    }
}
```

Which I would then call like this:

```
var app = {
    modules: {},
    init: function () {
        "use strict";

         this.modules.foo.init();
    }
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
   app.init(); 
});
```

Comment: Sure you can. It works, right?

Comment: It didn't work but I found out it was because I forgot to add the 'new' keyword. Now it looks like this: `app.modules.foo = new class {
    constructor() {
        // Module variables
    }

    // Module functions

    get init() {
        // Module initialization function
    }
}`

Comment: Is there any reason to use this instead of `app.modules.foo = (function() {})();` ? I would expect the classes to be more useful because they are extendable but haven't seen anyone using this inside the module pattern.

Comment: Ah, right, I missed that you wanted a singleton object, not a constructor. You should only use classes if you want to create multiple instances. [Do not use `new class {…}`!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38741262/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

Sure! It looks like you are trying to have modules represent singleton objects, and not classes that can be instantiated?
If this is the case, check out
    https://github.com/jojois74/recycle.js

Inside each module closure, you can create an object
`var obj = {};`
Add properties;
`obj.foo = function() {/*etc*/};`
Then return it:
`return obj.`

Take a look at the readme.md for details.

Comment: This looks very promising. Definitely going to take a look at it. Thanks!