# How to mock a ES6 singleton class with Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs, es6-class

I have a dependency that is a singleton class like so:

```js
// dependency.js
class Dependency {
   foo() { ... }
}
export default new Dependency();
```

I'm trying to mock this class with Jest but since its a singleton I'm not sure how to mock it. I tried this:

```js
jest.mock('../Dependency', () => {
  return { foo: jest.fn() };
});
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: How did it not work? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: Btw, [avoid singleton `class`es](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48368123/1048572) anyway!

Comment: Can you give more information? Is there any error?

Answer (score 2):

The `jest.mock` accepts a module name instead of a class name. The string should be the same as when you use `require`. Assuming your `dependency.js` is in the parent folder, it should be like this:

```js
jest.mock('../dependency', () => {
  return { foo: jest.fn() };
});
```

However, this requires the `'../dependency'` module to export a `foo`, like this: (see [More details on mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options))

```js
// dependency.js
// class Dependency {
   foo() { ... }
// }
export {foo};
```

Mocking a class is more complicated, you can see the implementation [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks)

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock an es6 module, which looks something like:

```js
jest.mock('./path/to/the/file', () => ({
    _es6module: true,
    default: {
        publicMethodMock: jest.fn(), // ... the rest of you methods
    }
    })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case singleton class looks like below. AbstractDataClient has 'someMethod' function.

```
class DataClient extends AbstractDataClient{

    constructor(){
        super(env.factoryId)
    }
}

export const dataClient = new DataClient()
```

To mock methods from AbstractDataClient inside some other test file I did:

```
import * as DataClient from '../../../src/common/client/DataClient'
const mockSomeMethod = jest.spyOn(DataClient.dataClient, 'someMethod')

mockSomeMethod.mockResolvedValue(Promise.resolve(true))
```