# Exporting ES6 classes with and without instantiating them with new() beforehand

Tags: javascript, es6-class, es6-modules

I've been reading about ES6 modules and have noticed that classes are either exported as-is, or after being `new`ed up.

For instance:

```
class Class1 extends SomeOtherClass {
   constructor() {
     super();
   }
   //Class1 methods and data here
}
export default new Class1();
```

..while in Class2.js:

```
class Class2 extends YetAnotherClass {
   constructor() {
     super();
   }
   //Class2 methods and data here
}
export default Class2;
```

Fair to assume that in the case of Class1 you've created a singleton, while with Class2 after importing it you can new up independent instances of it at will?  If so, are there other scenarios for using `new` when exporting a class vs not?

Comment: Well, [don't use `new class` to create singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38741262/1048572). ever.

Answer (score 1):

Using `new()` produces a new object from the constructor function, and if you return that you will return the object only. Without using it, you return the function itself instead.