# Instantiation and ordering of class causing bugs in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp

I'm using ES6 classes inside my game. I have two questions:

**Question 1)** I'm instantiating two singleton classes for `BattleMode` and `ExplorationMode` and passing in an initial parameter `type`.

Even though I'm console.logging `explorationMode` (an instance of `ExplorationMode`), it shows `Class BattleMode` with type `exploration`. Why is this?

**Question 2)** I'm using gulp with `babel` to compile scripts into `main.js`. Both `ExplorationMode` and `BattleMode` above inherit from parent class `Mode`. Gulp runs through `modes/` folder and adds them sequentially to `main.js`.

[image]

Apparently ES6 cares about the order of JavaScript, meaning if `BattleMode` is a child of `Mode`, then it will say it cannot find its parent.

> Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

This forces renaming of `mode.js` such that it appears first in the folder order. That's pretty hacky. If I prepend `A_mode`, the error goes away.

[image]

Is there a better solution for this besides renaming or specifying each parent in gulp to appear before its children?

Otherwise, I could just use Objects:

```
var Mode = Mode || {};

Mode.BattleMode = Mode.BattleMode || {
    doThing : function () {
         ...
```

---

**Question 1:**

```
class StateManager {
    constructor(type) {
        if (!stateManagerInstance) {
            stateManagerInstance = this;
        }
        this.type = type;
        const battleMode = new BattleMode('battle');
        const explorationMode = new ExplorationMode('exploration');

        console.log('MODE: ', explorationMode); // Wrong
        ...
```

Console Output:

> MODE: Class BattleMode  { type: "exploration" , screenState: "battle" }

Mode:

```
/*
  Define as Singleton
 */
let modeInstance = null;

class Mode {
    constructor() {
        if (!modeInstance) {
            modeInstance = this;
        }

        return modeInstance;
  }

}
```

ExplorationMode:

```
/*
  Define as Singleton
 */
let explorationInstance = null;

class ExplorationMode extends Mode {
    constructor(type) {
        super(type);

    this.type = type;

        if (!explorationInstance) {
            explorationInstance = this;
        }

    this.screenState = '';

        return explorationInstance;
  }
```

BattleMode:

```
/*
  Define as Singleton
 */
let battleInstance = null;

class BattleMode extends Mode {
    constructor(type) {
        super(type);

    this.type = type;

        if (!battleInstance) {
            battleInstance = this;
        }

    this.screenState = '';

        return battleInstance;
  }
```

---

**Question 2:**

Gulp:

```
gulp.task('build-dev', function() {
    gulp.run('scripts');
  gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', function() {
    gulp.run('scripts');
  });
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src([
            'js/**/*.js',
        ])
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['es2015']
        }))
        .pipe(concatJs('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js'));
});
```

Comment: Why is file system order determining the order your files are executed?  That should not be the case.  That is indeed hacky and your JS file execution order should have nothing to do with order in the file system.  Perhaps you need a container file that imports files in the proper order and you only run the container file.

Comment: Singletons are an invention of people that do not know objects.

Comment: @JonasW. I like that creational design pattern `:)` further, there are use cases. [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: "*I'm instantiating two singleton classes*" - [there's your first mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38741262/1048572).

Comment: @Ele The uses cases are mostly restricted to languages that have nothing but `class` constructs. JS is not one of those languages.

Comment: @Bergi perfect, but that doesn't change anything about my statement.

Comment: "*Is there a better solution for this besides renaming?*" - yes, of course. Always explicitly declare your dependencies between modules using `import`.

Comment: @bergi thanks. To be clear, es6 "new" is appropriate for everything but singletons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example why singleton can be antipattern. It provides extra complexity without real benefits. Children classes don't even benefit from inheritance.

Since both `BattleMode` and `ExplorationMode` inherit from `Mode`, `Mode` constructor is evaluated first. The first instance is saved to `modeInstance`. Since `BattleMode` is instantiated first, it's an instance of `BattleMode`, no matter what happens in child constructors.

In this case and many others singleton classes should just be replaced with plain objects.