# Uncaught TypeError: (destructured parameter) is undefined

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

I've been over this for a few days now, but I simply don't understand what's happening:
I have a `Serializable` class with 2 main methods, `serialize()` which just stringifies the instance and `wake(serialized)` which should wake up or "resurrect" an instance.

```
class Serializable {
  constructor() {}

  serialize() {
    return JSON.stringify(this);
  }

  wake(serialized) {
    // this is probably where the problem is and I don't really know how to approach it
    const unserialize = JSON.parse(serialized)
    return new this.constructor(unserialize)
  }
}
```

Then I declare `User` which extends from `Serializable`:

```
class User extends Serializable {
  constructor({
    firstName,
    lastName,
  }) {
    super();

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}
```

I create a `new User`:

```
let newUser = new User({
firstName: "Solid",
lastName: "Snake",
})
```

I serialize `newUser` and for example clarity I delete the instance:

```
const serialized = newUser.serialize()
newUser = null
```

Now I want to wake up the instance using the `serialized` constant:

```
const wakeUp = new User.wake(serialized)
```

This is where it fails. Error in Quokka is `Cannot destructure property 'firstName' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.` Error in console is the `TypeError` from the title.

Comment: The last part is what causing the issue. This is expected because your class depends on the properties `firstName`, and `lastName` in the constructor, plus you're de-structuring them hence you're getting this error.

Comment: `firstName = "Solid"` and `lastName = "Snake"` should be `firstName : "Solid"` and `lastName : "Snake"` for an object literal. And a comma is missing too between them. Don't type code when asking questions, but copy-paste.

Comment: Thanks, guys. @tevemadar yes, that was exactly what happened, lol. I mistyped when I was typing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the object literal typo:

- `ClassName.method()` style things are [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static), and they are still functions, not constructors
- for calling a constructor by hand, you need the `prototype`, [Calling ES6 class constructor from class static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49846475/calling-es6-class-constructor-from-class-static-method) could be a duplicate for that.

```js
class Serializable {
  constructor() {}

  serialize() {
    const name = this.constructor.name;
    return JSON.stringify(this);
  }

  static wake(serialized) {                               // 'static' added
    const unserialize = JSON.parse(serialized);
    return new this.prototype.constructor(unserialize);   // 'prototype' added
  }
}
class User extends Serializable {
  constructor({
    firstName,
    lastName,
  }) {
    super();

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}

let newUser = new User({
  firstName: "Solid", // no =, but ':' , also ','
  lastName: "Snake" // no =, but ':'
})

const serialized = newUser.serialize();
newUser = null;

const wakeUp = User.wake(serialized); // no 'new', it's not a constructor
console.log(wakeUp);
```