# How can I use a value returned from a function in my export default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, realm

I have a Realm class in React Native which defines my database. I want to use encryption but the key is retrieved from the Keystore.

RealmService.js

```
function getSecret() {
    // retrieve key
    // return value
    return "example";
}

export default new Realm({path: 'db.realm', schema: [Auth, Wiretransfer], encryptionKey: getSecret()});
```

The problem is that I get 0 errors but when opening the Realm db in Realm Studio the file is not encrypted. So I assume it is because the encryptionKey value is null at creation.

How can I use the return value of a function in my export default?

Comment: Why are exporting it ? Do you need to use it as a singleton somewhere else ?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling it as RealmService.method in my code.

Comment: Try exporting the instanciated object.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [named exports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_named_exports) instead:

```
const realmInstance = new Realm({path: 'db.realm', schema: [Auth, Wiretransfer], encryptionKey: getSecret()});
export { realmInstance };
```

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38741262/5698673) explaining why it's bad to use `export default new`

Comment: I'm using a named export now but still have the same issue. The key is being logged to console and Realm doesn't throw an error, yet it's not encrypted.

Comment: What does your `getSecret()` return ? What data type ? a string  ? According to [Realm Doc] 
(https://realm.io/docs/javascript/2.16.0/api/Realm.html#~Configuration), `encryptionKey` has to be either an `ArrayBuffer` or `ArrayBufferView`