# typescript initialize object with read-only property in-hand

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to initialize an object literal and declare its interface with read-only property in-hand at the same time ?

For example

```
let a = { readonly b: 2, readonly c: 3 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `as const` assertion:

```
let a = { b: 2, c: 3 } as const // typed as { readonly b: 2; readonly c: 3; }
a.b = 2 //Cannot assign to 'b' because it is a read-only property.
```

If you want only some props to be readonly, that is not really possible, best you can do is use an `Object.assign` with one part containing readonly properties and the other containing the mutable properties:

```
let a = Object.assign({ b: 2, c: 3 } as const, {
  d: 0
});
a.b = 2 // err
a.d = 1 //ok
```

Comment: but you can still change b and c property

Comment: No you can not. "Cannot assign to 'b' because it is a read-only property."

Comment: @JurajKocan wasn't the point to make the properties readonly ?

Comment: @ritaj what ts version are u using? i can still write this a.b = 3 with no error in ts 3.5.1

Comment: indeed it works ! I got an error writing a.b = 3. Using typescript 3.4.5

Comment: @JurajKocan Tried with `3.1.0`, and `3.4.5`.

Comment: @ritaj ok i had some problmes in vscode when switching version, just didnt show me the error

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I just discover that you still can change the nested object

Comment: @Quoc-HaoTran I assume you filed this issue, otherwise it would be a surprising coincidence :D https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31856. Will be fixed soon, it was a surprising bug though

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yes I filed it xD why is it a suprise ?

Answer (score 0):

"as const" is just a compile time error, not runtime error, have to use getter only property.

```
const a = Object.assign({ get b() { return 2 }, get c() { return 3 } }, {
d: 0
});
a.b = 2 // err
a.d = 1 //ok

alert(JSON.stringify(a))
```

FYI, Object.Freeze make whole object can't asssign new propeties

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA8gIwFYFNhQHRwQQCWA5mABQDeMpWsaFAlDDQE70CubYMATDAC%20AGlr0YwZqxgco3XgGYhQ0VQBQMTTAAmALhgAGNYKYBuNXDxok-GAHo7MLGzYW82mwEZ7dkAGs1CwAbZygKACkAZRQAOTxoNmIwUmIAMwBPCjgmJkDQSAYbdGxcAiIySmKcfFSOLAAvLGoYNH0%20UWB9JRMYVQ0dfSMTczQrGwEHJxc1UY9kbwd-QLgQtjCo2PioROS0zLQcoA), see transformed code, and run it

Answer (score -1):

you can write it with custom type

```
type Point = {
  readonly x: number;
  readonly y: number;
};
const a: Point = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
};

a.x = 2; // ERROR Cannot assign to 'x' because it is a constant or a read-only property.
```