# Specify that an object literal's property is readonly

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a way to mark an object literal's property as readonly. So that the following code would produce a compilation error:

```
const o = {
    p: true
};

o.p = false; // <== i want an error here
```

I obviously can do it like this:

```
const o: {readonly p: boolean} = {
    p: true
};

o.p = false;
```

But this is really clumsy.

Is there any more elegant way?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/56541293/1048572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make all properties readonly `as const` is a good option:

```
const o = {
    p: true
} as const;

o.p = false;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=14&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBCMF4YG8BQMMwA4C4ZQCcBXAU1QF8YBDCGUSKAblVRADotEYAzKgGwglGMIA)

If you want only some properties to be readonly, there isn't a good option ... `Object.assign` works but is rather clunky:

```
const o = Object.assign({
    nonRo: true
}, {
    p: true
} as const);

o.p = false; 
o.nonRo = false //ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBCMF4YHkBGArApsKA6AhhBAJYDmYAFAN4BQM9MY4ASiAFwxQBOArpjQF8ANDFoMYABw7c+gmIRihIUAJQBuGjRC4JiGADN8AGwiY1MLbiZhWewycwwA9E5ABrIA)

Comment: Actually, 'as const' is a really nice thing. I've somehow missed it. Thanks!

Comment: But it does not seem to work properly in this case:

```
const o = {
    p: true
} as const;

function foo(a: { p: boolean }): void {
    a.p = false;
}

foo(o); // <= I would expect a compilation error here
```

Comment: @DmytroGokun that is a completely different issue .. Ts is pretty lax with the readonly modifier and allows assignment to a non-read-only but compatible type 

Comment: Yeah, that's lame. This actually looked like a bug to me at first glance. But you are saying by design? Do you have any link to some sort of docs or discussion regarding this?

Comment: @DmytroGokun this is a discussion on teh topic: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347