# NodeJS importing class causing SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have created a service class and made it singleton:

```
class DiscordService {

    async getToken(code) {
        const creds = btoa(`${process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID}:${process.env.DISCORD_SECRET}`);
        const headers = {
            Authorization: `Basic ${creds}`,
        };

        const baseUrl = 'https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=';
        const url = `${baseUrl}${code}&redirect_uri=${process.env.DISCORD_CALLBACK_URL}`;

        const response = await axios.post(url, {}, {headers});

        return await response.data;
    }

}
export default new DiscordService();
```

I have imported that class in my routes file `discord.js`

```
import DiscordService from '../services/discord';
```

and I am using it like:

```
const response = await DiscordService.getToken(code);
```

When I run my server I get the following error:

```
import DiscordService from '../services/discord';
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Is it because its only allowed in typescript? or do I need babel for it ?

Comment: await is only available for use in asynchronous functions.

Comment: How do you load the `discord.js` file, and to which environment?

Comment: Btw, [don't export a `new class` instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38739499/1048572). Instead [use named exports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572)!

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854169/how-can-i-use-an-es6-import-in-node