# Why does `export default` export an object with `default` instead of the object itself?

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have three Typescript files:

config/env/development.ts

```js
import { Config } from '../config';

class DevConfig {
    public config : Config = {
        HOST: 'localhost',
        PORT: 8080
    };

    constructor() {
        this.config.HOST = 'localhost';
        this.config.PORT = (process.env.PORT as unknown as number) || 8080;
    }
}

export default new DevConfig().config;
```

config/index.ts

```js
import { Config } from './config';

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

class AppConfig {
    public allConfig : Config;
    public envConfig : Config;

    constructor() {
        this.envConfig = require(`${__dirname}/env/${process.env.NODE_ENV}.js`);
        this.allConfig = require(`${__dirname}/all.js`);
    }
}

export default new AppConfig().envConfig;
```

and the other file is:
./app.ts

```js
import * as express from 'express';
import { hi } from './controllers/status';
import AppConfig from './config';

class App {
    public express: any;
    public config: object;

    constructor() {
        this.express = express();
        this.config = AppConfig;
        this.mountRoutes();

        console.log(`Output test: ${JSON.stringify(this.config, null, 4)}`);
    }

    private mountRoutes() {
        const router = express.Router();

        router.get('/', hi);
        this.express.use('/', router);
    }
}

export default new App();
```

The output I see when I run this is the following:

> Output test: {
>       "default": {
>           "HOST": "localhost",
>           "PORT": 8080
>       }
>    }

Where is the "default" coming from? If I try to do `console.log(this.config.PORT);`, I get an `undefined`. Could someone please clarify?

Comment: Well, where is `{ "HOST": "localhost", "PORT": 8080 }` coming from?

Comment: That first file is the `./config` file, and it imports itself?

Comment: That comes from here `this.envConfig = require(`${__dirname}/env/${process.env.NODE_ENV}.js`);` I haven't included that file here. But it's similar to the first file.

Comment: You should not [export a class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38739499/1048572). Use [multiple named exports instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29893591/1048572).

Comment: So does the file that you `require` have a default export? Please post its contents, it seems very relevant (much more than the second file you posted).

Comment: @Bergi Yes, the `require` files have an `export default`. Just edited the question.

Comment: There you are, that's where the `default` is coming from. Have a look at the code that the Typescript compiler is producing.

Comment: Having same module names (`./config` and `../config`) can be dangerous. Not sure if that is relevant to the problem though.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, for those two links! I will remove the class instance to simply exporting the class (not default).

Comment: @JonasWilms Could you please elaborate on why my module structure is dangerous?

Comment: You might forget a dot somewhere, and the IDE won't spot it because you accidentally imported the wrong file ...

Comment: @JonasWilms The other Config is an `interface`, but point taken.

Comment: @codehitman In your case it seems much more appropriate to export an object literal, and not create a class at all. You already got the `Config` interface for type safety anyway.

Comment: @Bergi I'm going to be adding some methods to that `class` which will be called from within the `constructor.` Do you think it's better if I get rid of the `class` and just call the `function`s when the object is `import`ed? `export config = { host: 'localhost', firebase: () => {}, ... }` something like that?

Comment: @codehitman since you still want to export an object only(?), I doubt that you need *methods* that do anything with a class *instance*. Just write plain `function` declarations. If you want to export an object with methods, you can write method definitions in object literals too :-)

Comment: @Bergi Ok. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A module can have a `default export` *and* regular `export`s, yet `require()` can only return *one value*. Therefore the transpiler you are using has to turn multiple exports into one value. It does so by turning all the exports into an object.

```
  // this
  export default 1;
  export const named = 2;

  // turns into:
  module.exports = { 
    default: 1,
    named: 2 
  };
```

As `default` is a reserved keyword and thus cannot be used as a named export, having a `default` key for the `export default` makes perfectly sense.

You can easily get the default export with `require("...").default`.

Comment: …or alternatively just write `module.exports = {HOST: "localhost", PORT: process.env.PORT || 8080};` instead of that overengineered typescript stuff :-)

Comment: "*having a `default` key for the export default makes perfectly sense.*" - that's not just because `default` is a reserved keyword, rather the default export really is just a normal export with a special identifier that saves some typing. You could export and import is with "named" syntax as well.

Comment: I was about to mention json config, but using `process.env` requires a script.