# 'this' returns undefined in extended Classes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, undefined, babeljs, extends

I am trying to run the code below, but it is not working. I think this is a scope problem, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

```js
import CommonController from './CommonController';
import CategoryService from './category/Service.js';

class CategoryController extends CommonController {
  constructor() {
    super(CategoryService);
  }
}
export default new CategoryController();

// ===================CommonController==========================

export default class CommonController {
  constructor(service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  async get () {
    console.log(this); // it returns undefined
  }
}

// ===================CategoryService==========================
import Category from './Category'
import dto from './dto'

class CategoryService extends CommonService {
  constructor() {
    super(Category, dto);
  }
}
export default new CategoryService();

// ===================CommonService==========================

export default class CommonService {
  constructor(model, dto) {
    this.model = model;
    this.dto = dto;
  }
 }
```

if a run:

```js
import CategoryController from './CategoryController';

CategoryController.get()
```

the console.log in CommonController get function will print undefined

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your `this` is in the context of `async get ()` which may be undefined. Have you checked the *babel* docs on how to inject `this`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce, in the call `categoryController.get()` the `this` keyword refers to the `categoryController`.

Comment: "*Am I doing something wrong?*" - don't [default-export `new` class instances](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38741262/1048572). Either export the whole class, or simply use an object literal (or even [use named exports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29895235/1048572))

Comment: `async get service() {return await this.service}`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are calling `get()` on *the class itself*, instead of calling it on *an instance* of the class. Try creating an instance of `CategoryController`, like so:

```
cc = new CategoryController();
```

Then, you should be able to call:

```
cc.get();
```

Demo in the code below (same as yours, just slightly modified to reflect my point).

```js
// ===================CommonController==========================

class CommonController {
  constructor(service) {
    this.service = service;
  }
  
  async get () {
    console.log(this); // it returns undefined
  }
}



// ===================CommonService==========================

class CommonService {
  constructor(model, dto) {
    this.model = model;
    this.dto = dto;
  }
 }

// ===================CategoryService==========================
class CategoryService extends CommonService {
  constructor() {
    super(Category, dto);
  }
}

class CategoryController extends CommonController {
  constructor() {
    super(CategoryService);
  }
}
 
 
 cs = new CategoryController();
 cs.get();
```