# Exporting IIFE formated function to ES6 Module

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, iife

Having a little trouble with modules / IIFE etc. I have a script that used to be an IIFE and uses a lot of this key word etc.. I am trying to turn it into a module.

I have the following module **dice.js**:

```
export default function () {
this.createDice = function() { ... }
... 
}
```

on the main APP I call it as:

```
import Dice from "./dice.js";

let DICE = new Dice();
let dice1 = DICE.createDice();
let dice2 = DICE.createDice();
```

and it works... My question is, is there a way of avoiding creating an extra DICE variable to call all the methods? In other words I would like to call it like this:

```
import Dice from "./dice.js";

let dice1 = Dice.createDice();
let dice2 = Dice.createDice();
```

I've tried with IIFE but can't get it right.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In an IIFE you'd do

```js
export default (function () {
  function Dice() {
    this.createDice = function() { ... }
    ... 
  }
  return new Dice();
})()
```

But really, just do this

```js
function Dice() {
  this.createDice = function() { ... }
  ...
}
export default new Dice();
```

Comment: so simple... Thanks!!

Comment: "*But really, just do `export default new Dice();`*" - actually, [don't even do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38741262/1048572)

Comment: @Bergi - that's true