# How to declare efficiently a set and get functions for handling cookies in modern JavaScript with ES modules?

Tags: javascript, cookies, es6-modules

I'm currently working on a library that needs to have basic management for cookies (get and set). I could use [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie), but I try to avoid dependencies.

I was wondering what was the best approach to deal with this. Here are the different implementations I have thought of, but I'm not sure which one is more relevant, or maybe there is a better way to do it.

---

### 1. With two separate functions

```js
export function getCookie() {
    // code
};

export function setCookie() {
    // code
};
```

### 2. With a function and 2 methods

```js
export function Cookie {
    this.get = function () {
        // code
    };

    this.set = function () {
        // code
    };
}
```

### 3. With a class and 2 methods

**A. Classic way**

```js
export class Cookie {
    get() {
      // code
    };

    set() {
      // code
    };
}
```

**B. Export the instance**

```js
class Cookie {
    get() {
        // code
    };

    set() {
        // code
    };
}

export new Cookie();
```

**C. With static methods**

```js
export class Cookie {
    static get() {
        // code
    };

    static set() {
        // code
    };
}
```

---

Having your opinion will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are global, so we'll assume you do not need multiple instances of an object with methods. That rules out solutions #2 and #3A. It [also rules out #3B](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38741262/1048572).

If you just want to create two functions, there's absolutely no reason to place them on a `class`, so [don't use solution #3C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29895235/1048572) either. Go with solution #1, which is the simplest and most efficient.

Comment: After reading the solution of your first link, I wonder if this alternative option to 1 is pertinent: exporting an object literal in which I stored the two functions?

Comment: It's doable, but I would advice against it. Exporting named functions is cleaner. If you want to call them like methods on an object, you still can choose to do so individually by using a namespace import: `import * as cookie from '…'; cookie.get()` (while at the same time allowing `import { get as getCookie } from '…'` in other modules).