# TypeScript and proxying methods

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a JavaScript project that I am refactoring into TypeScript. However, I've encountered a TypeScript error (TS2339) that I cannot resolve.

I have a class

```
export const devtoolsBackgroundScriptClient = new class 
{
    constructor()
    {
        return this.asProxy();
    }

    // some methods

    asProxy()
    {
        return new Proxy(this, {
            get: (e, t) => {
                return void 0 !== e[t] ? e[t] : e.callBackgroundScript.bind(e, t);
            }
        });
    }

    callBackgroundScript(method, ...params)
    {
        // some code
    }
}
```

I call this class, like a

```
devtoolsBackgroundScriptClient.submitSurvey(surveyData);
```

Method submitSurvey doesnt exist in class, that's why called callBackgroundScript.
It works for javascript, but I have typescript error here:

devtoolsBackgroundScriptClient.submitSurvey(surveyData);

> Property 'submitSurvey' does not exist on type
> 'devtoolsBackgroundScriptClient'

How I can resolve ts warning?

Comment: TS doesn't know how to strongly type `Proxy` instances that do arbitrary things; nor does it model that returning from constructors change the instance type.  So we'll need a type assertion.  What type would you like `devtoolsBackgroundScriptClient` to have?

Comment: see prev comment.  I mean, maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKbV8m) is the behavior you want, but I'm not sure (and the intersection I used is only an approximation of what you're doing even if it's right).  I could write that up as an answer if it meets your needs; if not, please [edit] to clarify the behavior you need and how it differs from the type I suggested there.

Comment: @jcalz your example was useful for me, thanks.

Comment: Please [never use `new class { … }`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38739499/1048572)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript unfortunately currently has no way to model that a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) does anything to the type of its target.  So `asProxy()` return type is just the `this` type as if the proxy weren't there.  This is a known issue, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#20846](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20846).  It's classified as a bug but I'd think of it more as a missing feature.  Either way it's not part of the language so you'll need to work around it.

Furthermore, TypeScript currently has no way to model that a class constructor might `return` something different from the type of the class itself.  Even if `asProxy()` returned something more specific than the anonymous `this` type, the class constructor wouldn't notice it.  There is a longstanding feature request for the ability to annotate a class constructor's return type at [microsoft/TypeScript#27594](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27594).  Again, not part of the language, so you'll need to work around it.

The best you'll be able to do is come up with a type that works for you and then either [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that the value is of that type, or use some other type-loosening scheme like [the intentionally unsound `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  Here's one possible approach:

---

First, it's a nightmare to try to keep track of your class's non-augmented type when everything is anonymous.  I'm going to just use a class declaration instead of a class expression.  It's not *necessary* but it's a lot easier since it gives us a type name to work with:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
  }
  a() {
    console.log("called a")
  }
  callBackgroundScript(method: PropertyKey, ...params: any) {
    console.log(method, params)
  }
}
```

I added an example method in there also.  Note that I didn't bother to put the `Proxy` inside the class.  You were just using the class once, so it's more straightforward to put the class instance inside the proxy instead.  I don't want to think about what happens if someone calls `devtoolsBackgroundScriptClient.asProxy().asProxy()` anyway; it's better to just avoid that possibility.

Okay, here we go:

```
const devtoolsBackgroundScriptClient = new Proxy(new Foo(), {
  get: (e: any, t) => {
    return void 0 !== e[t] ? e[t] : e.callBackgroundScript.bind(e, t);
  }
}) as Foo & { [k: string]: (...params: any) => void }
```

The important piece of that is that `devtoolsBackgroundScriptClient` is of type `Foo & { [k: string]: (...params: any) => void }`.  That [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) is saying that it's both a `Foo` *and* a `{ [k: string]: (...params: any) => void }`.  The latter type has a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) and says that at every string key there is a method that takes any arguments.

Note that this type isn't quite accurate. Conceptually you'd want to say "every string key *except* for those already of `Foo`".  Unfortunately, there's no way to accurately represent such a type in TypeScript.  This is another missing feature: [microsoft/TypeScript#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867). Until and unless there is a way to do that, you'll (guess what) have to work around it.  See [How to define Typescript type as a dictionary of strings but with one numeric "id" property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431397/how-to-define-typescript-type-as-a-dictionary-of-strings-but-with-one-numeric-i) for various workarounds.  The intersection type here works pretty well in practice as long as you're not trying to create a value of that type without error, and the type assertion `as` already handles that for us.

Okay, let's try it out:

```
const surveyData = { a: 1 }
devtoolsBackgroundScriptClient.submitSurvey(surveyData); // okay, "submitSurvey" [{a: 1}]
devtoolsBackgroundScriptClient.a(); // okay, "called a"
devtoolsBackgroundScriptClient.a(surveyData); // compiler error (still emits "called a")
```

Looks good.  The compiler knows that the `a` method exists and does not allow arguments, while `submitSurvey` is allowed and treated like a method that accepts any arguments.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1rHgOwgFwCcBXYPeAgCgEoV1oBfOsa2jDLXeEAUwDoR4AcwoAiYGBA8AJtDAiqdRuwkgAQmGABrQQXhFsUgMrACASwAOeCgFtueABbwpALmgAFXee4E8ATwDS3L4ANNC84eZgBGDWEK5g2L40aGyYOBBcfALCtg5OoZHRsQoYjIyoHPjQUtwAbmRcEOpaOnoGxmaWAMIgptzYeNAAvNDY3ADu7roAHr4UY5MI8NShKdCCdq4U3PGJoXg0QwB8rGwEdkQE2NC18KYyAAzQAIRDI9wA2ngAutAA-NBPj9oK4+OJJM1tLp9EYTBY8LwAEamAzbfZUADcilQ9BokDgiGgADIUNAPppXPgzNhBN8tuFeIUYnFZIlDidbvcGKgKulBhBLrUggARMB4MDDUlgVwARm5NXqiBATQ0ULasM6eB6fQGvAFiOspjwhkFQQoAoIQt8ovFmOgAHp7dB4JowCFoCJ9YbjabfCIychpdAZfRvqgFQ1lZDWjCOvDtf0Ecw7Y7na73WIVNwZHJw3VIyqWtD2nDur1E7xmBarTawCmnVhrOZTDwCICCLo2+a8C2QIDvTBM5Js7J5DygA)