# Should I nest constructors and prototypes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

A project I'm working on currently has called for an object type `Chain` that itself produces a type of object `Link` that only it uses.
In previous projects, I had nested the object constructor and prototype of `Link` inside the constructor for `Chain`, however, I began to wonder this time if this was the best way to do this as I would actually be appearing to set up each `Chain` with its' own definition of `Link` every time.

For clarity, this was the original code I had:

```
var Chain = function() {
    var self = this;

    var Link = function(key) {
        this.prop = key;
    };
    Link.prototype.attach = function(args) {
        for (let value of args) {
            this[value.prop] = value.value;
        }
    };

    self.links = [];

}
Chain.prototype.add = function(key) {
    this.links.push(new Link(key));
}
```

I have then begun wondering if I should just store the `Link` constructor and prototype out in the wild like I have with `Chain` (for the record, it's not quite out in the wild, it's actually contained within a object) or whether I should use the prototype of `Chain` to define `Link` and keep it there.

I've failed to find much information on best practice in this situation, and while I strongly suspect my first way of doing things is not the best/right way; I'm not sure if my alternatives are either.

So I ask, what is the best practice/most efficient/sensible way to do this?

Comment: *Never* nest them. Chain them, yes, but never nest them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In previous projects, I had nested the object constructor and prototype of `Link` inside the constructor for `Chain`, however, I began to wonder this time if this was the best way...
>
> I have then begun wondering if I should just store the `Link` constructor and prototype out in the wild like I have with `Chain`

There's a third option: A single `Link` which is private to `Chain`:

```
var Chain = (function() {
    function Link() {
        // ...
    }
    // Link.prototype stuff here

    function Chain() {
        // ...
    }
    // Chain.prototype stuff here

    return Chain;
})();
```

Now, `Chain` is public, `Link` is private, but there's only one `Link` rather than creating a new one for every `Chain`.

This works equally well with ES2015+ `class` syntax:

```
const Chain = (function() {
    class Link {
        // ...
    }

    class Chain {
        // ...
    }

    return Chain;
})();
```

Comment: Now that is an interesting approach that I hadn't considered, and one I like. Curiously, you have also posited answered a second question I've had for a while, which is the tidiest way to define object constructors and their prototypes. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I began to wonder this time if this the best way to do this as I would actually be appearing to set up each `Chain` with its' own definition of `Link` every time.

Yes, that's exactly the reason not do this. You don't want to create thousands of `Link` classes when you create a thousand chains. Always place the class next to each other, never one in the constructor of the other.

Sometimes, an instance-specific helper function can be helpful (to set up a link belonging to that particular chain), but one can do that as a factory method and still keep all links from all chains share the same (base) class.

> Should I just store the Link constructor and prototype out in the wild like I have with `Chain`?

Yes, that's fine, as far as scope goes. Unless "the wild" is the global scope, there's nothing wrong with this. If you like to have some encapsulation, you can use ES6 modules to export only the "public" parts of that scope, or use an IIFE (like in @T.J.Crowder's answer).

Another common method that keeps the classes together, having one belong to the other, is to use the class as a namespace object:

```
var Chain = function() {
    this.links = [];
};
… // Chain.prototype

Chain.Link = function(key) {
    this.prop = key;
};
… // Chain.Link.prototype
```

The same [works with ES6 `class`es](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28784501/1048572).