# Efficient and elegant way to create nested ES6 classes?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object

While trying to find a way to use nested classes in JS, I came up with this sort of thing:

```
class Character {
    constructor() {
        this.Info= class I {
            constructor(name,value) {
                this.name=name;
                this.value=value;   
            }
        };
    }
    bar () {
        var trial = new this.Info("Goofy", 2);
        alert(trial.name);
    }
}

var test = new Character();
test.bar();
```

and it seems to work. However, I'm afraid this might be creating a new function object for each `new` call, as I define the class in the constructor (which is executed at each `new` call). Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784375/nested-es6-classes) does not solve my issue as the author only wonders how to even have a nested `class`; I'm already able to do that but I wonder if there's a more efficient way.

Comment: Have you considered creating *Info* as a [static method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) instead?

Comment: Nice one, but I guess it would mean falling back to the `function` syntax? I'd like to be able to use `class`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested ES6 classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784375/nested-es6-classes)

Comment: @filipe I've edited to explain why my question is different

Comment: So.. the most efficient way is to have it as static using any of the available nomenclature, or then just to not nest it !

Answer (score 5):

Using a static property in react, angular or just using babel, because direct static class properties are not currently implemented on all browsers.

```
class Character {

    static Info = class I {
        constructor(name) { this.name=name; }
    }

    bar () {
        return new Character.Info("Goofy");
    }
}

const test = new Character();
console.log(test.bar());
```

Using a static property the old way -- currently working on all browsers.

```
class Character {
    bar () { return new Character.Info("Goofy"); }
}

Character.Info = class I {
    constructor(name) { this.name=name; }
}

const test = new Character();
console.log(test.bar());
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't find the right syntax fast enough. :-)

Comment: Raises the question: why isn't there an easy way to reference a constructor from within the constructor? That would make it easier to call static methods.

Comment: @RobG, because the object is not created  yet when inside the constructor.

Comment: I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='. Expected an opening '(' before a method's parameter list.` at the line `static Info = class I {`.

Comment: @RobG, In chrome its on the current spec.

Comment: Then likely not a good solution. Fails in current Edge, Safari and Firefox. :-(

Comment: @RobG, use Character.Info = class ... its the same. We all use babel, and you should start to get used of it :-)

Comment: Also do you mean you have to assign it from outside to make it work on all browsers?

Comment: "We" don't all use babel. I can't support introducing a dependency like that, it's really no better than saying "use library X".

Comment: Babel is a transpiler not a dependency. It allow you to use all the javascript current and next stuff and it will transpire the code to any browser version. Babel is usually bundled with webpack.

Comment: `static #Info = class I { constructor(name) { this.name=name; } }` makes it possible to add private classes, and this is what I was looking for. But in `class Character { static #Info = class I { constructor() {} }; a = new Character.#Info(); }`, `class I`'s constructor, is still accessible after `var c = new Character(); var i = new c.a.constructor()`. So keep members private too.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the example you've given is too simple to demonstrate whatever problem you're trying to solve, but it seems to me you don't need to nest them at all.

```js
class Info {
  constructor(name, value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
  }
}

class Character {
  bar() {
    var trial = new Info("Goofy", 2);
    console.log(trial.name);
  }
}

const test = new Character();
test.bar();
```

Comment: I completely agree. Nested classes to make it look like a namespace. Well we already have the modules. The most eficiente way to nest two classes is to not nest them!