# Grouping class methods in Typescript/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi I want to achieve something like this in TypeScript/JavaScript

```
const foo = new something();
foo.group.method();
```

I've already tried using objects and it works just fine but I was wonder is this the best way to achieve this or not

My Code:

```js
class something{
    someMethod(){
       //do something
    } 
    group:{
       doSomething:()=>{
          //my grouped method
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: Be careful though - `this` will be the group and not the class instance.

Comment: @CherryDT Yeah I know that and typeScript fixes this issue but do you think this is the best way ?

Comment: May I ask why you want to do that? Does it have a purpose beyond simply logical grouping of related methods?

Comment: @seesharper I'm trying to develop a small library. I thought grouping related methods will make the documentation more understandable, and I've seen similar patterns in other frameworks or libraries so I decided to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *must* have the ability to call `foo.group.method()`, then you have no choice but to construct the `group` object with its associated methods when you create a `something`, most logically by doing so in `something`'s constructor. There really isn't any alternative syntactical sugar to let you group methods without their sharing an object. Even typescript's namespaces (different use case but a similar intention of logical grouping) actually use objects under the hood, because that's all JavaScript has. I would suggest that if the purpose is only logical grouping, then you probably shouldn't do it, because it is unconventional and is probably creating more complication than it's worth, but of course your use case may dictate otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer can you suggest any alternative solutions then ?

Comment: As this is a library, you may want to structure things differently, but it is hard to recommend how without knowing any details. Typically with a library you are exposing a lot of functions - you don't necessarily want them all on a big class/object, which will need to be constructed, thus unnecessarily consuming memory. I'd suggest exposing an API of functions which take the class instance as an object parameter, but as I say, hard to know without the details.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use modules and then set up module exports in a way that makes sense. Using CommonJS, it would be something like this:

```js
someMethod() {}
doSomething() {}

module.exports = {
  someMethod,
  group: {
    doSomething
  }
}
```

Edit: Also, [putting sub-classes as static properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784375/nested-es6-classes) might be something you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I want to do it in JavaScript classes because I need to store and use some variables in all of my methods.

Comment: Right check out the link I posted. The first answer in that post seems like something that might really help

Comment: Nope that's a whole other subject. but thanks anyway :))