# Is it possible to have a constructor function as a method in a class?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

In the following example the constructor function which creates a new node (here named `Node`) lies outside the class whose method calls it:

```js
class Collection {

  constructor() {
    this.collection = [];
  };

  addNode(value) {
    const node = new Node(value);
    this.collection.push(node);
    console.log(this.collection);
  };
};

function Node(value) {
  this.value = value;
}

const col = new Collection();

col.addNode("foo");
```

However, I'd like to have the constructor function inside the class (mainly because it's only used by that class). This will fail (`x is not a constructor`):

```js
class Collection {

  constructor() {
    this.collection = [];
  };

  Node(value) {
    this.value = value;
  };

  addNode(value) {
    const node = new this.Node(value);
    this.collection.push(node);
    console.log(this.collection);
  };
};

const col = new Collection();

col.addNode("foo");
```

I'm also aware that Javascript currently does not support nested classes. What I'm currently doing is simply declaring the `Node` constructor inside the `addNode` method.

But I'm curious: is it possible to have such constructor function iside the class that calls it?

Comment: "*I'm also aware that Javascript currently does not support nested classes*" - [are you sure about that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28784501/1048572)?

Comment: "*What I'm currently doing is simply declaring the `Node` constructor inside the `addNode` method.*" - please don't do that! This is creating a new, separate class every time the `addNode` method is called, you really don't want that.

Comment: @Bergi thanks a lot for pointing that. But now I'm confused: you start your answer saying *"there are no nested classes in ES6"*. So, JS supports nested classes or not? (I'm specifically talking about a `class` keyword inside another class)

Comment: Interesting.  Why is `this.Node` not a constructor?  It certainly seems to be a function, and I was under the impression that any function could be a constructor.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @Wyck Class methods do not have an internal `[[Construct]]` property and cannot be invoked with `new`.

Comment: @caTS I found [this answer to _How to check if a Javascript function is a constructor_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40922715/1563833) which provides an explanation to supplement your comment.  It explains why _Functions created via the arrow functions syntax or via a method definition in classes or object literals are not constructable._

Comment: @Megapteranovaeangliae I've edited the linked answer. What I meant was that you cannot just put a `class` declaration inside the body of a `class` and expect it to be available under the declared name in the methods of the outer class, which was what the OP was attempting to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: defining `Node` as an instance field and setting it to a function (basically your first example)

```js
class Collection {

  constructor() {
    this.collection = [];
  };

  Node = function (value) {
    this.value = value;
  };

  addNode(value) {
    const node = new this.Node(value);
    this.collection.push(node);
    console.log(this.collection);
  };
};

const col = new Collection();

col.addNode("foo");
```

Option 2: using a nested class (which is also an instance field)

```js
class Collection {

  constructor() {
    this.collection = [];
  };

  Node = class Node {
    constructor (value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
  }

  addNode(value) {
    const node = new this.Node(value);
    this.collection.push(node);
    console.log(this.collection);
  };
};

const col = new Collection();

col.addNode("foo");
```

Option 3: using either of the above, but making it a **static** field instead (recommended). This is so that the class is not re-created for every instance of `Collection` you create.

```js
class Collection {

  constructor() {
    this.collection = [];
  };

  static Node = function (value) {
    this.value = value;
  };

  addNode(value) {
    const node = new Collection.Node(value);
    this.collection.push(node);
    console.log(this.collection);
  };
};

const col = new Collection();

col.addNode("foo");
```