# ES6 - Call static method within a class

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I have this class which does an internal call to a static method:

```
export class GeneralHelper extends BaseHelper{
     static is(env){
          return config.get('env:name') === env;
     }

     static isProd(){
         return GeneralHelper.is('prod');
     }
 }
```

Are there any keywords I can use to replace the class name in the line below:

```
GeneralHelper.is('prod');
```

In PHP there are `self`, `static` etc. Does ES6 provide anything similar to these?

TY.

Comment: I've posted a more complex answer in a separate thread regarding this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43694337/3182819

Answer (score 81):

If you are calling the static function from inside an instance, the right way to refer to the static function of the class is:

`this.constructor.functionName();`

[Call static methods from regular ES6 class methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627908/es6-call-static-methods)

Comment: OP is not asking about calling it from an instance. (If he was, it would be a duplicate of the question you linked)

Comment: That's not even an answer. `this.constructor.is('prod')` would throw error in this case.

Comment: This is the solution when you want to call your static method when you are inside an instantiated class, Otherwise you just call `this.method()`. Also when you extend a class you call `super.method()`

Comment: Downvote because this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 64):

It's the same as [calling a method on an ordinary object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10711064/1048572). If you call the `GeneralHelper.isProd()` method, the `GeneralHelper` will be available as `this` in the method, so you can use

```
class GeneralHelper {
     static is(env) { … }
     static isProd(){
         return this.is('prod');
     }
}
```

This will however not work when the method is passed around as a callback function, [just as usual](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572). Also, it might be different from accessing `GeneralHelper` explicitly when someone inherits `isProd` from your class and overwrites `is`, `InheritedHelper.isProd()` will produce other results.

If you're looking to call static methods from instance methods, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28627908/1048572). Also notice that a class which only defines static methods is an oddball, you may want to use a plain object instead.

Comment: i think It's quite confusing use "this" keyword in a static context, but anyway it's working fine, thanks

Comment: @ShlomiSasson: Why? `this` is the class object on which the method was called, pretty standard… Is this greatly different in other languages?

Comment: Yes, in PHP $this refer to the current object you're within it's method, into class' methods (static) you don't have this keyword exist (you have 'self' and newest 'static').

As far as i remember, also in Java "this" keyword isn't available into a static method - and it's make sense: there is no "this" entity when you're into a static context.. "this" must talking about particular entity and into static method you're referring for the whole class or for general actions..

Comment: As a JS developer, it's very important to understand how `this` behaves. It does not work like `this` in other languages.

Comment: How to invoke the static method inside the **class constructor**?

Comment: @kidwon: A constructor invocation is quite like a method invocation, so it's [the same as there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28627908/1048572) (with the only difference of `this` not being usable before the super call).

Comment: @kidwon `constructor(){ CLASS_NAME.STATIC_METHOD(); }`

Comment: @kidwon Alternatively to using `this.constructor.method`, in the constructor you can also use `new.target.method`.

Answer (score 52):

Both of the answers here are correct and good, but I wanted to throw in an added detail based on this question title.

When I saw "ES6 - Call static method within a class" it sounded like "call a static method (from a non-static method) within a class". Def not what the initial question asker is asking in the details.

But for anyone who wants to know how to call a static method from a non-static method within a class you can do it like this:

```
class MyClass {
    myNonStaticMethod () {
        console.log("I'm not static.")
        MyClass.myStaticMethod()
    }

    static myStaticMethod () {
        console.log("hey, I'm static!")
    }
}

MyClass.myStaticMethod() // will log "hey, I'm static!"

const me = new MyClass()

me.myNonStaticMethod() // will log "I'm not static" and then "hey, I'm static!"
```

The idea is that the static method is can be called without creating a new instance of the class. That means you can call it inside of a instance's method the same way you'd call it outside of the instance.

Again, I know that's not what the detail of the question was asking for, but this could be helpful other people.