# Calling an overridden static method from parent

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

First, some code to set the stage:

```
var instances = [];

class Parent {
    static doImportantStuff() {
        console.log( 'Parent doing important stuff' );
        return false;
    }

    static init() {
        if ( this.doImportantStuff() )
            instances.push( new this() );
    }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
    static doImportantStuff() {
        console.log( 'Child 1 doing important stuff' );
        if (someCondition) return true;
        return false;
    }
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
    static doImportantStuff() {
        console.log( 'Child 2 doing important stuff' );
        if (someOtherCondition) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

The idea is that there's a class `Parent` that several `Child` classes extend. Initialization of the `Child` classes is mostly the same, but each has their own implementation of `doImportantStuff()`, the return value of which indicated whether that particular `Child` should be instantiated.

So far this has worked in each transpiler I've tried, because `this` in the `Parent.init()` function refers to the constructor of the `Child` class. However I haven't found any documentation saying one way or the other about referring to a static method overridden by a child class, so the question is, can I rely on this always being so? Or, is there some other way to do this?

Comment: What `this` refers to in `init` only depends on how the function is called. If you call it with `Parent.init()` then it refers to `Parent`. If you call it with `Child1.init()` then it refers to `Child1`. That has nothing to do with ES6, it's how JavaScript always worked (and ES6 does not change that).

Comment: There is something about extending here in "The extends clause" : http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [ES6 - Call static method within a class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31116300/1048572)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> However I haven't found any documentation saying one way or the other about referring to a static method overridden by a child class, so the question is, can I rely on this always being so?

It's the standard function-call-via-object-property mechanism. When you do:

```
Child1.doImportantStuff();
```

...unless `doImportantStuff` is an arrow function (it isn't) or a bound function (it isn't), then during the call, `this` is set to `Child1`. Exactly like:

```
var obj = {
   foo: function() {
        console.log(this === obj);
   }
};
obj.foo();   // "true"
```

So yes, you can rely on that. (And I understand why you asked, it does *seem* a bit odd unless you work it through.)

Of course, it won't work from within the code of a non-`static` function, because `this` will refer to the instance, not the constructor function. If you needed it there, you could use `this.constructor.doImportantStuff` unless someone's messed up the `constructor` property. (People always used to mess it up; with the new syntax automating it, hopefully that will happen less although it's rare you really need it...)

---

For these kinds of questions, it's frequently useful to remember that the new class syntax is *almost* just syntactic sugar for the old verbose way we did it (if we were really thorough). It's *really good* sugar, but that's nearly all it is (and that's a Good Thing™). `static` methods are set as properties of the constructor function, non-`static` methods are set up as properties of the object on the constructor's `prototype` property. (I think the only non-sugar aspect of it is, as [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) points out, that the new syntax lets us extend builtins like `Array` which it wasn't possible to do before. Part of making that possible relates to how and when `this` gets set up [you can't access it prior to the `super()` call in your subclass constructor], which relates to `new.target`, which Bergi [discusses here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32450516/1048572). In ES7, it may go further beyond sugar with privacy stuff.)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that class syntax was sugar in a permanent way, or in other words, I knew how it works with the transpilers, but I wasn't sure it would still work like that when implemented natively in browsers. I feared this behavior might be just an artifact of the ES version conversion, which would go away later, breaking my code. It's good to know that wont happen!

Comment: Inheritance is a bit more than sugar though. Especially we had no constructor functions inheriting from other constructor functions, which allows us to use `super` even in static methods

Comment: @Bergi: But again, that's just syntactic sugar. If I have `Child extends Parent`, then in a `Child` static method I use `super.staticMethod()`, the unsugared version is simply `Parent.staticMethod()`. It's true that ES6 has `Parent` in the prototype chain of `Child` (e.g., `Child -> Parent -> Function.prototype -> Object.prototype`), but we could do that with `setPrototypeOf`. It's `setPrototypeOf` rather than `class` that's the advance there. Don't get me wrong, I'm a big fan of the sugar, but for now I think that's all it is, isn't it? (Won't be very surprised if you catch me out here.)

Comment: Yeah, I guess most of `super` is desugarable, even the [[HomeObject]]. The only ES6 class thing that is not would be [newtarget](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32450516/1048572) then…

Comment: @Bergi: Ah, you've put your finger on it: The way the new syntax lets us extend builtins like `Array` is definitely not just sugar! (Even `new.target` is basically accessible in the "old" way as `this.constructor` -- assuming someone hasn't messed up the `constructor` property somewhere along the way -- but the wiring *is* slightly different, and better, with the new syntax. Knew I could count on you.)

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to call

```
Child1.doImportantStuff();
```

in `Parent`, but rather dynamically invoke the overridden static method, you can do:

```
this.constructor.doImportantStuff();
```

This also works for setters and in the constructor of the parent class:

```js
class Parent {
    static get foo() {
        // Throw an error to indicate that this is an abstract method.
        throw new TypeError('This method should be overridden by inheriting classes.');
    }

    constructor() {
        console.log(this.constructor.foo);
    }

    logFoo() {
        console.log(this.constructor.foo);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    static get foo() {
        return 'yay';
    }
}

const child = new Child(); // Prints 'yay'
child.logFoo(); // Prints 'yay'
```