# Create new instance of this using ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to create a new instance of self/this using ES6 inside a static method? For example;

```
class myClass {

  static model() {

    return new this;
  }
}
```

Is there a recognised pattern for this type of scenario?

Many thanks.

Comment: See also [How to create an instance of a subclass from the super class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50965142/1048572)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly how you'd do it.

If you don't want subclasses to use the subclass constructors, refer to your class by name explicitly, similar to [accessing other static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31117358/1048572).

Comment: @downvoters please explain why you think this is controversial (+2/-2)