# How to create an instance of a subclass from the super class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am creating a class and its subclasses, where I am required to call a static method of the parent to return a child instance.

```
class Animal{
  static findOne(){
    // this has to return either an instance of Human
    // or an instance of Dog according to what calls it
    // How can I call new Human() or new Dog() here? 
  }
}

class Human extends Animal{
}

class Dog extends Animal{
}

const human = Human.findOne() //returns a Human instance
const day = Dog.findOne() //returns a Dog instance
```

Comment: `return new this;`

Comment: @destoryer the findOne in the animal class should not know what calls it.

Comment: @Keith that does not work, it returns `this is not a constructor` error

Comment: @InfiniteDev Does it? Works for me…

Comment: Works for me in `Edge` / `Chrome` / `Firefox`,  what browser you using?   Just a though, the error your seeing, is not a Linting error is it?

Comment: @Keith I am using it in backend node

Comment: Works in node too, what version of node you using.?   And is kind of expected as it's based on Chromes JS V8 engine.

Comment: @Keith thank you it works. I had a the rules nested inside the function() i changed it to arrow function and it works perfectly.

Comment: LOL, not a problem.  Had me well confused!!, testing with the actual script shown in the future might not be a bad idea, just in case of side effects.  ps.  The reason why this works is due to how JS handles dot notation on objects and is actually nothing special,.. Basically `anything.something()`, `anything` is then set as `this` for `something` when called, seen as `anything` was the actual class, `this` got set to the class.  Hope that makes sense. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [static method is called](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31117358/1048572) with its `this` value being the class object, the constructor of the subclass that you called it upon. So you can just instantiate that with `new`:

```
class Animal {
  static findOne() {
    return new this;
  }
}

class Human extends Animal{
}

class Dog extends Animal{
}

const human = Human.findOne() // returns a Human instance
const dog = Dog.findOne() // returns a Dog instance
```

Comment: How to get some static properties of child class in findOne method

Comment: @AmarjitSingh Same, just `this.staticProperty`