# How do you access a private static method from a public static method of the same class?

Tags: javascript, class, overloading, static-methods, private-methods

My JavaScript method overloading implementation below can't access my private static method in ***line 10***. It seems the `#` symbol cannot be embedded into a string.

**JavaScript Code**

```js
 1 'use strict';
 2 
 3 class MyClass {
 4   static myFunction() {
 5     let length = arguments.length;
 6     let methodName = `#myFunction${length}`;
 7 
 8     console.log(methodName);
 9 
10     if (MyClass[methodName]) {
11       return MyClass[methodName](...arguments);
12     }
13     else {
14       throw new ReferenceError();
15     }
16   }
17 
18   static #myFunction0() {
19     console.log('__myFunction0__');
20   }
21 
22   static #myFunction1(x) {
23     console.log('__myFunction1__');
24   }
25 
26   static #myFunction2(x, y) {
27     console.log('__myFunction2__');
28   }
29 }
30 
31 let x = new MyClass();
32 
33 console.dir(x);
34 console.dir(MyClass);
35 console.log(MyClass.myFunction());
36 console.log(MyClass.myFunction(1));
37 console.log(MyClass.myFunction(1, 2));
```

**Console Output**
![Console output of the JavaScript code]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZlun.png)

Although it works if I turn all the methods into public and non-static, but I would like to hide `myFunction0()`, `myFunction1()`, and `myFunction2()` methods without resorting to other means, for the sake of readability. Is there any way to access my private static methods inside my public static method of the same class?

---

**Dynamic Private Property Access Solution**

It works with the help of `eval()` and `try...catch` in ***lines 9-14***. *It even works for non-static private methods as well!*

Does anybody know the performance impact in ***line 10***?

```js
 1 'use strict';
 2 
 3 class MyClass {
 4   static myFunction() {
 5     let length = arguments.length;
 6     let methodName = `myFunction${length}`;
 7     let method;
 8 
 9     try {
10       method = eval(`MyClass.#${methodName};`);
11     }
12     finally {
13       // Nothing here, just syntax requirement
14     }
15 
16     console.group(`CALL FROM ${methodName}`);
17     console.log(methodName);
18     console.log(method);
19     console.groupEnd(); console.log('\n');
20 
21     if (method) {
22       return method(...arguments);
23     }
24     else {
25       throw new ReferenceError();
26     }
27   }
28 
29   static #myFunction0() {
30     console.log('__myFunction0__');
31   }
32 
33   static #myFunction1(x) {
34     console.log('__myFunction1__');
35   }
36 
37   static #myFunction2(x, y) {
38     console.log('__myFunction2__');
39   }
40 }
41 
42 let x = new MyClass();
43 
44 console.dir(x);
45 console.dir(MyClass);
46 MyClass.myFunction();
47 MyClass.myFunction(1);
48 MyClass.myFunction(1, 2);
49 MyClass.myFunction(1, 2, 3);
```

**Console Output**
![Console output of the JavaScript code]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJYS6.png)

Comment: It's not a problem with private methods, it's just that you can't access instances methods from static methods.

Comment: @CesarePolonara It very much is a problem with the field being private - you cannot access those dynamically.

Comment: As the for the title question "*How do you access a private static method from a public static method?*", the answer is: [as always](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31116300/1048572) - using either `this.#myMethod()` or `MyClass.#myMethod()`.

Comment: @Bergi but before he edited the question, he was trying to access those methods not declared as static, inside the static method, as long as I know that can't be done whether they are private or not.

Comment: @CesarePolonara Ah ok, I didn't find that revision in the edit history

Comment: @Bergi I don't know, unless I was hallucinating, I'm almost sure that was the first revision lol, but yeah I can't find it either now...

Comment: Thanks guys. I think there is really no way to use `#` dynamically during runtime. Any hack-ish solution? Better make all my methods public and non-static, then add `Proxy` to prevent access to `myFunction0()`, `myFunction1()`, and `myFunction2()`, and expose the proxied class to the user.

Comment: I updated my post above with a possible solution. I think `eval()` and `try...catch` approach would be less hassle than using `Proxy`, or function wrapping, but I am worried with the performance impact of using `eval()` in this case.