# calling prototype methods from javascript constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, methods, constructor

I have the following simple inheritence pattern and I would like to know if it's ok to call methods the way i do from within the constructor function (basically speaking, using `this` instead of "super prototype".

Parent class, `Pet`

```
function Pet(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.nickname = name;

  this.adopt();
}

Pet.prototype.adopt = function() {
  this.nickname = 'Cutty ' + this.name;
}

Pet.prototype.release = function() {
  this.nickname = null;
}

Pet.prototype.cuddle = function() {
  console.log(this.name + ' is happy');
}
```

Subclass, `Lion`

```
function Lion(name) {
  Pet.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments); // super(name)
  this.cuddle();
  this.release();
}
Lion.inherits(Pet);

Lion.prototype.adopt = function() {
  // DTTAH
}

Lion.prototype.release = function() {
  Pet.prototype.release.call(this);
  console.log('Thanks for releasing ' + this.name);
}
```

`inherits` helper (polyfills are bad I know)

```
Function.prototype.inherits = function(Parent) {
  function ProtoCopy() {}
  ProtoCopy.prototype = Parent.prototype;

  this.prototype = new ProtoCopy();
  this.prototype.constructor = this;
}
```

My pets are instantiated like so `var lion = new Lion('Simba')`

In Lion constructor,
Can I keep using `this` when calling sub/parent class methods ? Or should I use methods from parent prototype directly ? (like pseudo call to `super()` or in `release()`)

Reasons why I am asking are:

- `this` substitution at runtime
- `constructor` property not always what we are thinking (from what I read here and there)

I am not sure how these things can influence the resulting object.

Thanks for your enlightenment !

Comment: Your `inherits` function has side-effects, I'd recommend using `Object.create`.

Comment: You should omit the `.prototype.constructor` part everywhere.

Comment: That `Pet.prototype.constructor.release();` super call is wrong. Your probably meant `Pet.prototype.release.call(this);`

Comment: I don't want to provide this as a full answer, but rather a piece of advice to consider having a look at Klass.js http://github.com/ded/klass - it allows calling `this.super()` with ease.

Comment: @elclanrs what kind of side effects ? this was the part i was the most confident on !

Comment: @Bergi yes indeed i meant `.call(this)`. Otherwise I would modify the prototype from inside :) I'll edit the post

Comment: @Jordan: Still, the `.constructor` part is wrong, `release` is not a method on the constructor function but on the prototype.

Comment: @Bergi yep my bad. edited that as well. But what about the super construction part ? Isn't using `constructor` just being more specific than calling, say, `Pet.call` ?

Comment: One more thing, I realized the correct question might rather be, _What is the difference between using `this.fn()` and `MyClass.prototype.fn.call(this)` in a constructor function_ (instead of comparing "this" to "super prototype") 
Trying to answer that, I would say nothing. Except typing way more character in the second version.

Comment: @Jordan: Indeed it is. I'll answer it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between using `this.fn()` and `MyClass.prototype.fn.call(this)` in a constructor function?

This is not specific to constructor functions, it's the same in all functions (methods) that are called on instances.

Indeed there's not much difference apart from the character count when `this.fn === MyClass.prototype.fn`, and they would behave exactly the same. However, this assumption is not always true - `this` might not inherit from `MyClass.prototype` directly, but rather be a **subclass instance**, and that subclass might have **overwritten** the `this.fn` method.

So which one is correct? Both, in fact. If you know the difference, you can choose the appropriate one for your case. Other languages have different default expectations here, see also for [calling static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28648214/1048572).

Notice that you cannot replace the class reference by `this.constructor`, which would be overwritten as well. In a reasonable setup<sup>1</sup>, `this.fn()` would be always equivalent to `this.constructor.prototype.fn.call(this)`.

This is similar to the reason why super calls must explicitly reference the super class, and not depend on instance properties (such as `this.constructor`, `this.super` or anything similar).

<sub>1: Where `this.fn` is a usual method inherited from the prototype, not an own instance-specific one, and where every prototype has the `.constructor` pointing to the respective constructor whose `.prototype` it is.</sub>

Comment: About this part:
"_Notice that you cannot replace the class reference by this.constructor, which would be overwritten as well_"

Are you talking about an explicit and targeted overwrite of the `constructor` property or a side effect of some other operation ?

Comment: Yes, when subclassing the `.constructor` is explicitly overwritten. You'll have to use `Pet`, not `this.constructor`, because the latter might refer to `Lion`.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying the problem, consider the following code in ES6:

```
class Pet {
  constructor (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.talk();
  }
  talk () {
    console.log('My name is ' + this.name);
  }
}

class Lion extends Pet {
  constructor (name) {
    super(name);
  }
  talk () {
    super.talk();
    console.log('I am a lion.');
  }
}
```

would be equivalent to:

```
function Pet (name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.talk();
}
Pet.prototype.talk = function () {
  console.log('My name is ' + this.name);
};

function Lion (name) {
  Pet.call(this, name);
}

// inheritance:
Lion.prototype = Object.create(Pet.prototype);
Lion.prototype.constructor = Lion;

// override .talk
Lion.prototype.talk = function () {
  Pet.prototype.talk.call(this);
  console.log('I am a lion');
}
```

Running `new Lion('Bobby')` logs:

```
My name is Bobby
I am a lion
```

Further reading: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/10/22/classical-inheritance-in-javascript-es5

Comment: isn't the inheritance part missing from your example ? I get `lion instanceof Pet === false`

Comment: @Jordan ahh, my bad, I forgot that part. There are two lines that will now return `lion instanceof Pet` to be true. It's in the article as well, just forgot it.