# es6 variable scope with extended class and modules

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, node-modules

Why does es6 not allow this? I understand that message is only defined in the alert module and is undefined in the base module, but I (apparently wrongly) imagine that since the alert class has access to it, all of the class should... Thoughts?

```
//file component.js
import Base from './base';
const message = "hello";
class Alert extends Base {
    initialize() {
        this.render();
    }
}
export default Alert;
```

and

```
//file base.js
class Base {
    render() {
        alert(message);
    }
}
export default Base;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because JavaScript has [**lexical** scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping), not dynamic scope.

Lexical scope means that whether a variable is accessible or not depends on where they appear in the *source text*, it doesn't depend on runtime information.

Simplified example:

```
function foo() {
  var bar = 42;
  baz();
}

function baz() {
  console.log(bar); // error because bar is not in the scope of baz
}
```

**Note:** This is not new for classes or ES6, that was always the case.

Comment: This articulates exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `Base` class and it's methods don't have access to any of the variables in the `component` module, which has its own scope. It could gain access to the exported values if it would import the module, but not to the local `message` variable.

I think you'll want to use static properties of the class here, to which the `Base` methods would have access when called on an `Alert` instance:

```
import Base from './base';
export default class Alert extends Base {
    initialize() {
        this.render();
    }
}
Alert.message = "hello"; // not constant, though; you'd need to use
                         // Object.defineProperty(Alert, "message", {value: …} for that
```

```
export default class Base {
    render() {
        alert(this.constructor.message);
    }
}
Base.message = "";
```

<sub>See also [es6 call static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28627908/1048572) for how `this.constructor.…` works.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for answering! I wasn't so much concerned with a work around, but with an understanding of the limitation.

Comment: Yeah, I just didn't want to repeat what Felix already wrote :-)