# Access statically defined variable in class definition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I have a class:

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
    static store = createStore();

    constructor() {
        super();
        // This doesn't work
        console.log(this.store);
    }
}
```

and I want to be able to access the `store` variable defined at the top of the class however I'm not sure how, I had assumed it was by using `this.store` but it is undefined.

Comment: `this` is an instance, not your class. It doesn't have a `store` property? Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28627908/1048572)

Answer (score -1):

So basically you want to share the variable between all class instances? Try to pass it to constructor. Something like this:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.store = props.store;

    console.log(this.store);
  }
}
```

your init function:

```
function init() {

  var props = {
    store: createStore()
  };

  ReactDOM.render(<Home {...props} />, document.getElementById('home1'));
  ReactDOM.render(<Home {...props} />, document.getElementById('home2'));
  ReactDOM.render(<Home {...props} />, document.getElementById('home3'));
}
```

and html:

```
<div id="home1"></div>
<div id="home2"></div>
<div id="home3"></div>
```